# Efficient way to combine SparseArray objects?

Tags: list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

I have several SparseArray objects, say sa11, sa12, sa21, sa22, which I would like to combine into the equivalent of `{{sa11, sa12}, {sa21, sa22}}`.
As an example, I have :

```
sa11 = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}, {4, 4 3}] -> {{ConstantArray[1, 3]}}] 
sa12 = SparseArray[Join[Band[{1, #}, {4, 4 3}] -> 1 & /@ Range[1,  4 3, 4]]]
sa21 = SparseArray[Join[Band[{1, #}, {3, 4 3}] -> 1 & /@ Range[1, 4 3, 3]]] 
sa22 = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}, {3, 4 3}] -> {{ConstantArray[1, 4]}}]
```

I am able to generate the big SparseArray with :

```
sa = SparseArray[Join[{Band[{1, 1}, {4, 4 3}] -> {{ConstantArray[1, 3]}}}, Band[{1,     #},{4, 2 4 3}] -> 1 & /@ Range[4 3 + 1, 2  4 3, 4], Band[{4 + 1, #}, {4 + 3, 4 3}] -> 1 & /@ Range[1, 4 3, 3], {Band[{4 + 1, 4 3 + 1}, {4 + 3, 2 4 3}] -> {{ConstantArray[1, 4]}}}], {4 + 3, 2 4 3}]
```

Is there an efficient way to achieve this in general ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`ArrayFlatten[{{sa11, sa12}, {sa21, sa22}}]` seems to be what you need. It automatically merges everything into one big `SparseArray[]`.

Comment: ohhh, there goes my checkmark!

Answer (score 12):

How about `ArrayFlatten` ([docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayFlatten.html)):

```
sa2 = ArrayFlatten[{{sa11, sa12}, {sa21, sa22}}]
sa==sa2
(*
True
*)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know ArrayFlatten worked on SparseArray[] too.

Comment: I see I was only 18 seconds ahead of you. I upvoted your fine answer as well. :)

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the answers given (`ArrayFlatten`), there may be cases when the `SparseArray`-s need to be accumulated one-by-one, and keeping them all in memory at the same time may be too expensive.  [I've written a generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596134/efficient-alternative-to-outer-on-sparse-arrays-in-mathematica/8609071#8609071) to gradually accumulate `SparseArray`-s. Here is the code:

This is the low-level API for SparseArray construction / deconstruction, explained in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525782/import-big-files-arrays-with-mathematica/7527064#7527064) (where the code slightly differs):

```
ClearAll[spart, getIC, getJR, getSparseData, getDefaultElement, 
  makeSparseArray];
HoldPattern[spart[SparseArray[s___], p_]] := {s}[[p]];
getIC[s_SparseArray] := spart[s, 4][[2, 1]];
getJR[s_SparseArray] := spart[s, 4][[2, 2]];
getSparseData[s_SparseArray] := spart[s, 4][[3]];
getDefaultElement[s_SparseArray] := spart[s, 3];
makeSparseArray[dims_List, jc_List, ir_List, data_List, defElem_: 0] :=
     SparseArray @@ {Automatic, dims, defElem, {1, {jc, ir}, data}};
```

This is the function itself. It accepts the code which is supposed to generate the next piece, wrapped in `Hold`.

```
Clear[accumulateSparseArray];
accumulateSparseArray[Hold[getDataChunkCode_]] :=
  Module[{start, ic, jr, sparseData, dims, dataChunk},
   start = getDataChunkCode;
   ic = getIC[start];
   jr = getJR[start];
   sparseData = getSparseData[start];
   dims = Dimensions[start];
   While[True, 
     dataChunk = getDataChunkCode;
     If[dataChunk === {}, Break[]];
     ic = Join[ic, Rest@getIC[dataChunk] + Last@ic];
     jr = Join[jr, getJR[dataChunk]];
     sparseData = Join[sparseData, getSparseData[dataChunk]];
     dims[[1]] += First[Dimensions[dataChunk]];
  ];
  makeSparseArray[dims, ic, jr, sparseData]];
```

Based on this function, it is not difficult to write a function that will do what you need:

```
Clear[sparseArrayFlatten]
sparseArrayFlatten[m_?(MatrixQ[#, MatchQ[#, _SparseArray] &] &)] :=
 Module[{joinRow, code},
   joinRow[row_List] :=
     Module[{i = 1},
        With[{l = Append[row, {{}}]}, code := l[[i++]]];
        accumulateSparseArray[Hold[Transpose[code]]]
     ];
   joinRow[joinRow /@ m]]
```

Now:

```
In[109]:= 
sparseArrayFlatten[{{sa11,sa12},{sa21,sa22}}]==ArrayFlatten[{{sa11,sa12},{sa21,sa22}}]
Out[109]= True
```

Note that my solution will only pay off if you do have a situation with a huge number of `SparseArray`-s, which you would like to process lazily (or, which are created one by one). One of situations when this happens is during the data transfer, as explained in my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525782/import-big-files-arrays-with-mathematica). I was also able to significantly improve efficiency by using this technique for efficient initialization of a certain sparse array, in my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909732/how-can-i-efficiently-initialize-this-sparse-array-in-mathematica) question. I consider this to be a rather general technique.