# How to combine SparseArray and If

Tags: sparse-arrays

Because I am dealing with huge matrixes, my computer can not handle it, because of the memory. But, in my matrix, a very small percentage of the elements are non-zero. So I should use SparseArray as far as I am aware. The problem is that, I do not really know how to transform my old way of defining my matrix to the new "SparseArray way". I gonna give a very simple toy model of my old way:

```
n = 3;

H = ConstantArray[0, {n*n, n*n}];

Do[
  i = ix + (iy - 1)*n;
  j = jx + (jy - 1)*n;
  x = ix;
  y = iy;
  If[i == n && j == i - 1, H[[i, j]] = t*Exp[I*x],
   If[i == n && j == i + n, H[[i, j]] = t,
    If[i == n && j == i - (n - 1), H[[i, j]] = t*Exp[-I*x],
     If[i == n && j == i + n*(n - 1), H[[i, j]] = t, 0]]]],
 {iy, 1, n,1}, {ix, 1, n, 1}, {jy, 1, n, 1}, {jx, 1, n, 1}];
```

So my matrixes are like this but with many-many If.

Could somebody give me an idea of how to do it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I can recommend the article in the Documentation Center as a nice introduction, http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/WorkWithSparseMatrices.html

Answer (score 3):

It may not be highly time-efficient ([read this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/777/121)) but you can make `Part` assignments to a `SparseArray` object just as you would a conventional array, therefore you merely need to replace your `ConstantArray` with:

```
SparseArray[{}, {n*n, n*n}]
```

You can also specify a different background for the array with the third argument:

```
SparseArray[{}, {n*n, n*n}, 5]
```

Please take a look at this question, as explicit loops are rarely optimal in *Mathematica*:
[Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121)

By the way you should avoid starting user symbols with capital letters (unless you know exactly what you're doing) to avoid conflicts with built-ins, so use `h` instead of `H`.

---

After looking at your code in depth I believe you would be served by something like this:

```
n = 3;

SparseArray[
 {i_, j_} :>
  With[{x = Mod[i, n, 1]},
   Which[
    i != n,             0,
    j == i - 1,         t*Exp[I*x],
    j == i + n,         t,
    j == i - (n - 1),   t*Exp[-I*x],
    j == i + n*(n - 1), t,
    True,               0
    ]
   ],
 {n*n, n*n}
]
```

I observe that all but one row of the resultant array is entirely zero.  Of course it will be far more efficient to identify this pattern and program accordingly, but I assume that this code is merely an illustration of the kind of operation you wish to perform and not representative of the operation itself.

Comment: It might be more profitable for OP if he recasts the rules implemented as nested `If[]`s as actual rules within `SparseArray[]`...

Comment: Maybe I could do something similar to this:

Comment: mat = SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i == j :> 1, {8, 8}];

Comment: But what is the way to put more than one condition as I did, i==j:>1, but many of them ?

Comment: @Mencia you just need to put them in a list: `SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i == j -> -2, {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> 1, {i_, j_} /; i != j && j == 5 :> i + j}, {10, 10}] // MatrixForm`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks alot!!!! Appreciate your help! But the thing is, that I have this Exp functions with x in the argument which is correlated to {i,j} in the following way:

Comment: i = ix + 2*(iy - 1)*n;
j = jx + 2*(jy - 1)*n;
x = ix;
y = iy;

Comment: Is there anyway I can introduce this inside SparseArray ?

Comment: @Mencia I specifically didn't attempt to implement your program as I am tired, don't feel like it, and would probably make a mistake anyway.  I'm hoping someone else responds.  If they do not in a day, leave a new comment and I'll take a shot at an "elegant" implementation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok, cool, thankyou! Have a nice rest :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I still have not been able to figure out how to do it. So,if you are still in for the "elegant" implementation :), that'd be absolutely great!!

Comment: @Mencia I have updated my answer.