# Memory used by SparseArray objects

Tags: memory, sparse-arrays

In dealing with a quantum mechanics problem, I am representing some many-body states in two different ways in *Mathematica*. For two parameters `n` and `l` the representations are

1. A list of length `n` which is a partition of `l` into integers, 0 included, sorted in decreasing order.
2. A list of length `l+1` counting how many times each integer 0,...,`l` occurs in representation 1.

An example: for `n=4,l=5`, a state could be either represented as

1. `{3,1,1,0}`
2. `{1,2,0,1,0,0}`

where the latter list is interpreted as "one 0, two 1's, zero 2's etc".

Typically `n` is small, 10 or so, while `l` is maximally `l=n(n-1)`. This means that representation 2 is often very sparse when all integer partitions are considered, so I'm using `SparseArray`'s to store them. However today I did the followig:

```
Sum[ByteCount[c2[a]], {a, dim}]
(* 4 087 776 *)

Sum[ByteCount[Normal@c2[a]], {a, dim}]
(* 2 009 328 *)
```

where `c2[a]` is representaton 2 of state number `a` and `dim` is the number of states. What gives??

EDIT: I generate the set of all representation-1 lists with

```
c1 = IntegerPartitions[l, {n}, Range[0, l]];
dim = Length[c1];
```

Then, the following sets up representation 2:

```
counter[i_, l_] :=
 Block[{tally},
  tally = Tally@Reverse@c1[[i]];
  c2[i] = SparseArray[{#1 + 1} -> #2 & @@@ tally, l + 1]
  ];
Scan[counter[#,l]&,Range[dim]]
```

Comment: Probably `ByteCount` doesn't count correctly. Try `MaxMemoryUsed[<definition of c2>]` instead. (It is undocumented, so the argument will be highlighted in red. But it works.) It would be helpful for the question if you could provide the code to generate some test arrays.

Comment: @OleksandrR., thanks, see my edit. How in this case would I try your suggestion...?

Comment: There's no free lunch on sparsearrays - with the exception of MMA functions where elements (even when "small") are themselves represented sparsely and appear to be optimized for space "under the covers", it probably makes no sense to create a swarm of relatively tiny sparsearrays - create an empty one (`SparseArray[{},10]`) and do a bytecount to see the overhead (WRI staff chime in if I'm spouting nonsense). Why not create an empty SA large enough, then populate it in chunks (so c2[[]] to ref. instead of c2[])?  Worked fine on old netbook for n,l = 10,90 test with expected space savings...

Comment: @ciao, you are right. I created a single `SparseArray` and checked the `ByteCount`, and it was indeed smaller than the `Normal` matrix. However, I need to modify copies of the c2[a] and do lookups of which new index a' I end up at. In the process I modify lots of the default elements, and due to what Leonid wrote [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/777/efficient-by-element-updates-to-sparsearrays?rq=1) I'm starting to think `SparseArray` is not the tool for this job after all.