# How do I dynamically update a SparseArray?

Tags: sparse-arrays

Say I have a "seed" `SparseArray` e.g. `m=SparseArray[{1->1}]`. How do I add a rule at a position that has not yet been defined e.g. `5->5`to get a list of rules `{1}->1, (5)->5`? I want to build up the sparse array an element at a time. I don't want to have to normalise it as that would appear to defeat the purpose of sparse arrays

It seems like this should be simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient by-element updates to SparseArrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/777/efficient-by-element-updates-to-sparsearrays)

Comment: Building `SparseArray`s entry-by-entry _cannot_ be efficient.

Comment: Are you reading the array while building it, or only writing to it?  If only writing, you don't need to create a SparseArray.  The rules are sufficient. If you need a little bit of reading, consider `Association`, `AssociateTo` for updating, and `Lookup` (with a default of 0) for reading.

Comment: In the end I used an `Association`. I was misunderstanding `SparseArray` semantics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the `SparseArray` how large it will be when you initialize it, then you can just use `Part` and `Set` to update it:

```
m = SparseArray[{1 -> 1}, {10}];
m[[3]] = 3
(* 3 *)

Head@m
(* SparseArray *)

Normal@m
(* {1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

From the comments, I would suggest that an `Association` is a better data structure for this purpose.  You can build it up efficiently, and quickly dump it to a SparseArray at the end,

```
data = <|1 -> 2|>;

(* do something *)
data[4] = 22;
(* do something else *)
data[233] = 55;
(* now that you are done, make a SparseArray *)
SparseArray[ Normal @ data]
(* SparseArray[Automatic, {233}, 0, {
 1, {{0, 3}, {{1}, {4}, {233}}}, {2, 22, 55}}] *)
```

It will work for a higher dimension array,

```
data = <|{1, 1} -> 2|>;
data[{45, 33}] = 22;
data[{1000, 233}] = 55;
SparseArray[ Normal @ data]
```

[image]

You can access the stored values, and provide a default value just like for an array

```
Lookup[data, Key[{1000, 233}], 0]
(* 55 *)

Lookup[data, Key[{1000, 234}], 0]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: But I don't know how big it will be. I suppose if its internal representation is the least bit efficient I could initialise it to, say, a million elements without incurring too much of a penalty, but that seems ugly.

Comment: I wonder then if `SparseArray` is the right tool to use for this, see the edit

Comment: I think that you may well be correct. Thanks.