# Optimization of a slow function - reason to why it is slow

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction, sparse-arrays

**Edit:**

Okay, my question was viewed quite a few times but not answered so I assume I phrased/presented in a confusing way. I'll try to rephrase my problem to make it more accessible because luckily I figured out what caused my function to be slow as well as a rather simple fix and this might be useful for anyone that runs into a similar problem in the future.

Here's the slow code:

```
(*//////*)
(*Assembly of the global [K]-Matrix*)
(*//////*)

(*"empty" [K]-Matrix*)
kGlobal=SparseArray[{},{nodes,nodes}];  

(*Function that adds one element "e" to the global[K]-Matrix*)
  kAssembly[e_]:=(
   n1=conMatrix[[e,1]];
   n2=conMatrix[[e,2]];
   n3=conMatrix[[e,3]];

   kGlobal[[n1,n1]]=kGlobal[[n1,n1]]+kElement[[e,1,1]];
   kGlobal[[n1,n2]]=kGlobal[[n1,n2]]+kElement[[e,2,1]];
   kGlobal[[n1,n3]]=kGlobal[[n1,n3]]+kElement[[e,3,1]];

   kGlobal[[n2,n1]]=kGlobal[[n2,n1]]+kElement[[e,2,1]];
   kGlobal[[n2,n2]]=kGlobal[[n2,n2]]+kElement[[e,2,2]];
   kGlobal[[n2,n3]]=kGlobal[[n2,n3]]+kElement[[e,3,2]]; 

   kGlobal[[n3,n1]]=kGlobal[[n3,n1]]+kElement[[e,3,1]];
   kGlobal[[n3,n2]]=kGlobal[[n3,n2]]+kElement[[e,3,2]];
   kGlobal[[n3,n3]]=kGlobal[[n3,n3]]+kElement[[e,3,3]];
                  );

(*Executing the function for every element to assemble the entire global [K]-matrix*)   
Do[kAssembly[e],{e,1,elements}];
```

So what am I doing here:

I have a created a mesh beforehand and this mesh is built by nodes that are connected into Triangluar elements. Those connections are stored in the connectivity matrix `conMatrix`. Each row of the connectivity matrix has 3 values - the **global** numbers of its nodes, the first global node represents the **elements** first node the 2nd the 2nd node and so on. it looks something like this

$$conMatrix=\begin{bmatrix}1&3&2\\3&4&2\\3&5&4\\&...&\end{bmatrix}$$

Also beforehand I calculated the Stiffness - so called [K]-Matrix for each element, that's `kElement`. It represents relations between the nodes (for example k12 is the relation between node 1&2 in that element). `kElement`consist out of the symmetric [K]-matrices of each element. Because it's symmetric, you can save 3 calculations per element and I didn't calculate it entirely:

$$kElement=\begin{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}k11&&\\k21&k22&\\k31&k32&k33\end{bmatrix}_{Element1},&\begin{bmatrix}k11&&\\k21&k22&\\k31&k32&k33\end{bmatrix}_{Element2},&...\end{bmatrix}$$

During the so called Assembly, the relations between each node on a global scale get described. In the `conMatrix` Example I gave, it is apparent, that global node 3 is part of Elements 1,2,3. That means that global $K_{11} =K_{22,Elem.1}+K_{11,Elem.2}+K_{11,Elem.3} $. Same goes for every other connection - for example elements can also share lines.

This assembly process is what `kAssembly` is doing. The function first extracts the elements nodes out of `conMatrix`, then it adds the values at the right position in `kGlobal` which is a `SparseArray`. The function delivers the correct result and works reasonably fast in small meshes. However the `SparseArray` hits dimensions > 20,000 x 20,000 it starts to become incredibly slow. 25,000 x 25,000 (with 176,000 non-zero values) took 275 seconds (on a really fast computer).

After some tinkering with `SparseArray` I realized that if you gradually add a lot of nonzero values to a `SparseArray` one at a time every  following addition to the `SparseArray` becomes slower and slower. I did a little test to emphasize that by continously redcording the time after another 500 values were added to a `SpraseArray` - you can see the time increases slowly but in a exponential fashion and then there's some sort of bend (not sure what's going on):

[image]

Comment: Hard to say anything with incomplete code. We need all the definitions of the functions and variables involved in order to run your code.

Comment: there are pastebin links to the complete code (step 1: mesh generation, step 2: rest) in  the original post. I'll try to edit the rest of my code in though now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To put it short**:

it was the way I assembled my `SparseArray`. If you gradually add a lot of nonzero values to a `SparseArray` every  further addition to the `SparseArray` becomes slower and slower. This is also described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/779/57790).

**Longer answer:**

So it would be much better to Assemble the `SparseArray`in one single step in a `{node,node} -> value` fashion. my problem though was that I would have had the same `{node,node}` expressions with different values (that need to be summed up) associated to them. `SparseArray` however ignores duplicate mentions and simply takes the first. So in a case `{3,3}->1,{3,3}->3` it would add `1` at position `{3,3}` instead of the desired `4`.

In [Mr.Wizards answer to another problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37607/57790), I've found a solution to this problem though.

The option `SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}];` does automatically sum up duplicate entries.

With that in mind, I built 2 functions to create the global node "coordinates"/indexes as well as the associated values for every element:

```
index[e_]:=(
            {n1,n2,n3}=conMatrix[[e,1;;3]];
            {{n1,n1},{n1,n2},{n1,n3},{n2,n1},{n2,n2},{n2,n3},{n3,n1},{n3,n2},{n3,n3}})    

values[e_]:=(
              k11=kElement[[e,1,1]];
             {k21,k22}=kElement[[e,2,1;;2]];
             {k31,k32,k33}=kElement[[e,3,1;;3]];
              k12=k21;k13=k31;k23=k32;
             {k11,k12,k13, k21,k22,k23, k31,k32,k33})
```

This allows me to apply those functions to every Element with `Table`s and then flatten them into a list:

```
ind=Flatten[Table[index[e],{e,1,elements}],1];]
val=Flatten[Table[values[e],{e,1,elements}],1];]
```

with all values and indexes known, all that's left is building the `SparseArray`:

```
SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"->{"TreatRepeatedEntries"->1}];
kGlobal=SparseArray[ind->val];]
```

The lists `ind` and `val`took 0.2 & 0.3 seconds the `SparseArray` took 0.08 second. Significant speed-up compared to the 275 seconds before.