# Replace values in sparse matrix

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

I am interested in updating the values of the sparse matrix. I have a list of matrix element which I am interested in updating and a list of new values. Currently, I do it in the following manner:

```
s = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> i}, {100, 100}];
newP = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {5, 2}];
newV = RandomReal[1, {5}];
MapThread[(s[[#1[[1]], #1[[2]]]] = #2) &, {newP, newV}]
```

Any suggestions on how to do it more efficiently?

Comment: In you actual use case: Are the new positions among the nonzero positions of the old array?

Comment: No, I am updating  sub-set of  nonzero values of the matrix

Comment: `Module[{nzp = Join[newP, s["NonzeroPositions"]],
nzv = Join[newV, s["NonzeroValues"]]}, SparseArray[nzp->nzv, Dimensions[s]]]` seems to be faster.

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: [(777)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/777/efficient-by-element-updates-to-sparsearrays) – that question deals with element-by-element updates, whereas this question permits bulk replacement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
s = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> i}, {10000, 10000}];

newP = RandomInteger[{1, 10000}, {4000, 2}];
newV = RandomReal[1, {4000}];

s1 = s;
MapThread[(s1[[#1[[1]], #1[[2]]]] = #2) &, {newP, newV}] // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 1.93

```
(s2 = With[{nzp = Join[newP, s["NonzeroPositions"]],
      nzv = Join[newV, s["NonzeroValues"]]}, 
     SparseArray[nzp -> nzv, Dimensions[s]]]) // 
  RepeatedTiming  // First
```

> 0.0019

```
(s4 = With[{mask = SparseArray[newP -> 1, Dimensions[s]], 
      ns = SparseArray[newP -> newV, Dimensions[s]]}, (1 - mask) s + 
      mask ns]) // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0012

```
s1 == s2 == s4
```

> True

Versus Mr.Wizard's method:

```
RepeatedTiming[
    s3 = s +  SparseArray[newP -> newV - Extract[s, newP], Dimensions[s]];
  ] // First
```

> 0.0016

Comment: Interesting; `s4` is significantly slower than the others on my system, timing `0.00270`.  A variation of that was the *first* thing I tried.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, please note that i had changed 5000 to 4000 to avoid memory limits of free cloud plan. The timings i posted are obtained in Wolfram Cloud (v11.3).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, in version 9 s4 is slower than both s2 and s3.

Answer (score 2):

Compared to kglr's answer this is marginally faster on my system (version 10.1), and a little simpler.  It may be acceptable in many cases, however it will not work if you are trying to update Real to Integer values for example, because by way of numeric operations the Integers will be cast to Real.

```
s + SparseArray[newP -> newV - Extract[s, newP], Dimensions[s]]
```

Timings:

```
(* example code from kglr's answer *)

s = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> i}, {10000, 10000}];
newP = RandomInteger[{1, 10000}, {5000, 2}];
newV = RandomReal[1, {5000}];

(* his method again for comparative timing *)

(s2 = 
    Module[{nzp = Join[newP, s["NonzeroPositions"]], 
      nzv = Join[newV, s["NonzeroValues"]]}, 
     SparseArray[nzp -> nzv, Dimensions[s]]]) // RepeatedTiming // First

(* my method *)

RepeatedTiming[
  s3 = s + SparseArray[newP -> newV - Extract[s, newP], Dimensions[s]];
] // First

(* confirm equivalence *)

s2 == s3
```

> ```
> 0.00162
>
> 0.00145
>
> True
> ```