# Support for Compressed Sparse Column sparse matrix representation

Tags: export, import, data-format, sparse-arrays

Is there native support for [Compressed Sparse Column](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_column_.28CSC_or_CCS.29) (CSC) format for sparse matrices, like importing and manipulating them?

Comment: Why exactly are you focused on CSC and not CSR?

Comment: I am working on/modifying a code which has adopted CSC format - dats y

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first Google hit for "compressed sparse column" is [this page](http://netlib.org/utk/papers/templates/node92.html), which explains that it's also called the [Harwell-Boeing format](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/HarwellBoeing.html).  If this is what you need, this format is supported by Mathematica.

Answer (score 9):

*Mathematica* has, I think, very efficient [SparseArray](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html) functionality. SarseArrays are supported by a wide variety of functions, e.g `LinearSolve`, `Eigensystem`... The `SparseArray` is stored in [CSR](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#7977) (Look for the SparseArray entry). If you are interested [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Nov/msg00460.html) is a description of the internals. For the `Import`/`Export` you could either make use of the [HarwellBoeing](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/HarwellBoeing.html) format (as pointed out by Szabolcs) or make use of the positions and values and then create the `SparseArray` using:

```
positions = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {1, 3}};
values = {1, 2, 3, 4};
sa = SparseArray[positions -> values]
```

To extract positions and values from SparseArrays use:

```
sa["NonzeroPositions"]
(*{{1, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}*)
sa["NonzeroValues"]
(*{1, 4, 2, 3}*)
```

and then export those. "Properties" has more info.

[Here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00335.html) is a link where examples of efficient use of `SparseArrays` was discussed and it shows the addition of values into the same position. But there are many more cases where `SparseArrays` are useful. In fact, I think, they are quite underestimated.

Comment: +1. I was not aware of all these Mathgroup discussions. Another possibly relevant link in this context: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276/efficient-way-to-combine-sparsearray-objects/287#287

Answer (score 1):

You can view [the full list of supported formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListingOfAllFormats.html).  You can also view [the list of formats by category](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html).

You can evaluate [`$ImportFormats`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24ImportFormats.html) or [`$ExportFormats`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24ExportFormats.html) for a simple list of formats available.

Comment: Have checked it - nothing useful there

Comment: @myaccount_ram then perhaps the answer is: "No."

Comment: Szabolcs's answer solves it .. Thanks