# How to interpret the FullForm of a SparseArray?

Tags: implementation-details, sparse-arrays

`SparseArray`s are atomic objects, but they do have a `FullForm` which reveals information about them.

What is the meaning of the various elements in the full form of a `SparseArray`?  Did the structure change between Mathematica versions, and is it documented anywhere?

---

**Update:** In recent versions of Mathematica the LibraryLink documentation has a [useful description of the internal SparseArray structure](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithWolframLanguage.html#918619650).

Comment: It seems to be the same as `InputForm` which is mentioned: [Whenever a sparse array is evaluated, it is automatically converted to an optimized standard form](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SparseArrays-ManipulatingLists.html) But it doesn't have much detalis

Comment: I can't tell much about the changes from version to version, but the "API" I use in many of my answers,e.g. [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276/efficient-way-to-combine-sparsearray-objects/287#287) gives some idea. I give more details on the meaning of these parts [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525782/import-big-files-arrays-with-mathematica/7527064#7527064).

Comment: Based on ``ElisionsDump`HeldSparseArrayData`` it looks like `SparseArray[data_,dims_,def_,{___,elems_}]`, where `dims` is the dimensions and `elems` is number of non-default elements.  I'm not sure about `def` and `data`.

Comment: `def` is the "background", or default, value. `data` seems always to be `Automatic`, and I don't know what it represents.

Comment: Inviting Silvia to post an answer she provided in the comments [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44874/89).

Comment: *"`SparseArray`-s are considered to be atomic objects for pattern matching "* - this is not quite true (see my answer), and this is actually quite important, because `SparseArray`-s are fully represented by their `FullForm`, in the sense that, if you combine a `SparseArray` expression from pieces (like it is done in my answer below), you get a valid `SparseArray` object. To my mind, this is an important property. It does not hold for some other atomic objects (e.g. `Graph`-s), which some of us consider rather unfortunate.

Comment: @Leonid You are right of course, but that statement originated from the docs. I'm afraid that the trend of nonatomic objects represented as atoms (often inconsistently) will be the standard, seeing all kind of `Entity` objects appearing in the preliminary documentation.

Comment: I've corrected a small typo and added it into Leonid's CW.

Comment: @IstvánZachar The links from the accepted answer give complete information about this.  I had to understand them completely to add sparse array support to MATLink.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have described the details [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Nov/msg00460.html) and [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Nov/msg00560.html). The second post describes the version number of the sparse array implementation, which is still at version 1. So no big changes since it's introduction and V9.

If you like to read about sparse arrays I can recommend [this](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718881) from Tim Davis.

Answer (score 18):

Reposting my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525782/import-big-files-arrays-with-mathematica/7527064#7527064) (its relevant part about SparseArray)

#### The anatomy of sparse arrays

We start with a generally useful API for construction and deconstruction of `SparseArray` objects:

```
ClearAll[spart, getIC, getJR, getSparseData, getDefaultElement, makeSparseArray];
HoldPattern[spart[SparseArray[s___], p_]] := {s}[[p]];
getIC[s_SparseArray] := spart[s, 4][[2, 1]];
getJR[s_SparseArray] := Flatten@spart[s, 4][[2, 2]];
getSparseData[s_SparseArray] := spart[s, 4][[3]];
getDefaultElement[s_SparseArray] := spart[s, 3];
makeSparseArray[dims : {_, _}, jc : {__Integer}, ir : {__Integer}, 
     data_List, defElem_: 0] :=
 SparseArray @@ {Automatic, dims, defElem, {1, {jc, List /@ ir}, data}};
```

Some brief comments are in order. Here is a sample sparse array:

```
In[15]:= 
ToHeldExpression@ToString@FullForm[
   sp  = SparseArray[{{0,0,1,0,2},{3,0,0,0,4},{0,5,0,6,7}}]
]

Out[15]= 
    Hold[
      SparseArray[
        Automatic,
        {3,5}, (* Dimensions *)
        0,     (* Default element *)
        {
          1,
          {{0,2,4,7},{{3},{5},{1},{5},{2},{4},{5}}}, (* {ic, jr} *)
          {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} (* sparseData*)
        }
      ]
    ]
```

(I used `ToString` - `ToHeldExpression` cycle to convert `List[...]` etc in the `FullForm` back to `{...}` for the ease of reading). Here are the meanings of the parts:

- `{3,5}` are obviously dimensions.
- Next is `0`, the default element.
- Next is a nested list, which we can denote as `{1,{ic,jr}, sparseData}`. Here:

  - `ic` gives a total number of nonzero (non-default) elements as we add rows - so it is first 0, then 2 after first row, the second adds 2 more, and the last adds 3 more.
  - The next list, `jr`, gives positions of non-zero elements in all rows, so they are `3` and `5` for the first row, `1` and `5` for the second, and `2`, `4` and `5` for the last one.

  There is no confusion as to where which row starts and ends here, since this can be determined by the `ic` list.

  - Finally, we have the `sparseData`, which is a list of the non-zero elements as read row by row from left to right (the ordering is the same as for the `jr` list).

### Supplement:

*(The following interpretation is a **guess** based on Silvia's observation.)*

Suppose we have an array $A$ with dimension $N_1 \times N_2 \times \cdots \times N_n$,($n>1$): $\{A_1,A_2,\dots , A_k, \dots , A_{N_1}\}$, with the unspecified value (*i.e.* the background) being $b$.

And inside any $A_k$, there are $C_k$ numbers other than $b$: $\{\xi_{k,1},\xi_{k,2},\dots,\xi_{k,C_k}\}$, which located at positions $\{\rm{pos}_{k,1},\rm{pos}_{k,2},\dots,\rm{pos}_{k,C_k}\}$. So every $\rm{pos}_{k,\_}$ is a one-dimensional list with length $n-1$. (Except for the case of $A$ whose dimension is $1$ itself.)

Let $C_0=0$. Than the **`SparseArray`** expression of $A$ would be:

[image: SparseArray syntax]

Comment: any idea what the `Automatic` does?

Comment: My guess is that it is needed to differentiate the long form (to which the short form auto-evaluates), from the short form itself - but I am not sure.

Comment: By "nonzero" (`ic`) you mean "nondefault"? Or does `SparseArray` always use 0 internally to denote the default?

Comment: @IstvánZachar I meant "non-default". Thanks, corrected.

Comment: That would make sense, ie `Automatic` is basically a placeholder to fill the argument slot that would be *data* in the documented forms.

Comment: Notice if you set about adding and removing elements the elements in the flat list end up not in the expected order across rows  (I cant tell if you captured that in your notation or not..).

Comment: @george2079 I don't follow you here. Please provide a specific example.

Comment: Take your example then do `sp[[1, 1]] = 8`.  The `8` ends up not first in the flat list but third. (evidently inserted at the end of the group of elements that make up the first row)

Comment: another interesting example try this.. `spp = sp; sp[[1, 3]] = 0; sp[[1, 3]] = spp[[1, 3]]; sp === spp`

Comment: @george2079 Ok, that's a good point, and I did not account for this. The thing is, within each row, there is a freedom oh where to put the new elements, because the only requirement is that we have a list of positions, and that the `ic` has been modified correctly, so that we know how to split the list between rows. Do, we could have `{{3}, {5}, {1}, {1}, {5}, {2}, {4}, {5}}}, {1, 2, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}` (which is what we have), or e.g. `{{1}, {3}, {5}, {1}, {5}, {2}, {4}, {5}}}, {8, 1, 2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`, and this would've been equally valid.

Comment: @george2079 So, apparently, the current implementation adds the newly set element to the end for the part of the lists which correspond to a given row where the element has been added - which is one possible choice, but not the only one. You asked why not at the start  - well, it does not have to. All that matters is that the two lists are consistent with each other, and that we do have a list of positions - it is enough to reconstruct the original list correctly.