# Bug with SparseArray selector in Pick

Tags: list-manipulation, bugs, sparse-arrays

**Bug introduced in version 8 or earlier and fixed in 10.0**

---

I have created a notebook with two cells. This is the content of the first:

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}]
```

And this is the content of the second:

```
g
listDegree = VertexDegree[g]
vl = VertexList[g]
nodeMaxDegree = Pick[vl, listDegree, Max[VertexDegree[g]]][[1]]
aM = AdjacencyMatrix[g];
vLM = aM[[VertexIndex[g, nodeMaxDegree]]];
nN = Pick[vl, vLM, 0]
```

If I evaluate the second cell (after processing the first) for a **second** time:

1. the first time no problem, the results are correct;
2. **the second time the vertex list of `g` is inexplicably wrong but the graph remain correct!!**

I don't understand the cause because the graph `g` is never touched.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Interesting: `FullForm[vl]` gives ``List[1, System`Private`InternSequence[], System`Private`InternSequence[], System`Private`InternSequence[], 5, 6]``.

Comment: What does it means "System`Private`InternSequence[]"?

Comment: Adam, we were probably never supposed to see that symbol. I bet most WRI employees don't even know what it is does as it is in a private context. Who knows though :)

Comment: Adam, I've modified your title to better reflect the case. Could you please submit this as a bug report for the TechSupport at WRI?

Comment: Sure! Can you tell me how? I'm still a newbie :D

Comment: By the way, `System'Private'InternSequence[]`(by itself, without a wrapper like `List`) "evaluates to" `StandardForm`. Peculiar :P

Comment: Adam, can you please report this to support?  This is not an official Wolfram site, so they might never see the bug if it's not reported through the official channels (support @ wolfram.com).  We would of course all like to see it fixed, so do report it please!

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom, I expect that comes from ``Typeset`MakeBoxes[_, StandardForm]`` not having a rule for ``System'Private'InternSequence[]`` like it does for `Sequence[]`

Comment: @SimonWoods hmm let's call that function `sPI` for short. If you use a rule to transform `sPI[]`, like in `sPI[] /. x_ :> x`, it will evaluate to `Sequence[]`. I thought it might have to do with that. I've never looked at `Typeset'Makeboxes`, your guess is probably better than mine. By the way your `Spelunk` gives an error for that one.

Comment: I reported the issue to WRI.

Comment: @Jacob That is not a problem of Simon's `Spelunk` but the way how `MakeBoxes` definitions are returned and converted to boxformat: just try for example `Attributes[LabeledSlider] = {}; FullDefinition@LabeledSlider` and be prepared for LOTS of errors...

Comment: The bug seems to be no longer present in version 10!

Comment: @Jacob Do you know in which version this bug first appeared?  I'd like to add the appropriate version banner to this post.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard well, the bug with `SparseArray`, as illustrated by istvan's answer, is present in version 7 (I could not test earlier versions). The code by the OP first causes trouble in version 8, as the `Combinatorica\`` package in version 7 had different syntax.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bug in `Pick` caused by `SparseArray`, has nothing to do with `Graph`. Minimal example (`SparseArray` object is the fullform version of your `vLM`):

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
Pick[x, SparseArray[Automatic, {6}, 0, {1, {{0, 3}, {{2}, {3}, {4}}}, {1, 1, 1}}], 0];
FullForm@x
```

> ```
> {1, System`Private`InternSequence[], System`Private`InternSequence[], 
>     System`Private`InternSequence[], 5, 6}
> ```

As you can observe, the value of `x` gets updated though no assignment is done: those members are replaced in `x` which are listed in the `SparseArray` (2, 3 and 4).

One obvious solution for your case is to wrap the `AdjacencyMatrix` into `Normal` so its result won't be a `SparseArray`.

Comment: Nice István! I will continue to avoids SparseArrays another day :P. That syntax scares me.

Comment: Is `InternSequence` used `Private`ly to splice interns into the WRI `System`? :D

Comment: @rm-rf Veeeery suspicious indeed :). A new kind of exploitation of cheap workforce perhaps?

Comment: @Jacob It's a pity that the internal structure of SparseArray is not documented. I have no idea what most of those numbers are for.

Comment: @IstvánZachar hm this may have nothing to do with graph, but we end up changing the vertex list

Comment: Nice discovery. Horrible bug - it happens even if `x` is `Protected` and `Locked`.

Comment: I notice it doesn't happen if `x` is a packed array, e.g. try with `x = Range[6]`

Comment: @IstvánZachar but if you ask the `VertexList` of the graph again, it gives you the same broken thing!

Comment: @Jacob Yes, you are right, sorry. This is indeed scary: it actually modifies `g` (check with `FullForm`) and not simply `VertexList@g`!

Comment: Nice work! And here is my guess of [the syntax of the `SparseArray`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OsO1C.png)! :)

Comment: @Silvia Plausible hypothesis, it deserves its own thread!

Comment: Thanks. If you think it's useful, please feel free to add it into your answer. :) And I still don't know the other possible value for `Automatic` and the `1`...

Comment: @Silvia, please post your answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44893/sparsearray-internal-structure)!

Comment: @Silvia and Istvan, the 1 is for the sparse array version number

Comment: @rm-rf Interesting... It reminds me there is a version number in `CompiledFunction`, too.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a bug to me. Here is a slightly more minimal example.

```
ue = UndirectedEdge;
g = Graph[ue @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}}];
vl = VertexList[g]
aM = AdjacencyMatrix[g];
vLM = aM[[VertexIndex[g, 1]]];
Pick[vl, vLM, 0];
VertexList[g]
```

Output

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}  
> {1, 5, 6}
> ```

You can solve the error by making a copy of the vertexlist yourself. This can be done by using `Append` and `Delete` as follows

```
ue = UndirectedEdge;
g = Graph[ue @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}}]
vl = Delete[Append[VertexList[g], 0], -1]
aM = AdjacencyMatrix[g];
vLM = aM[[VertexIndex[g, 1]]];
Pick[vl, vLM, 0];
v1 = VertexList[g]
```

Output

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}  
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
> ```

So in your case you could do

```
copy[list_] := Delete[Append[list, 0], -1];

g
listDegree = VertexDegree[g]

Block[
 {punchingBag},
 punchingBag = copy[VertexList[g]]; 
 nodeMaxDegree = 
  Pick[punchingBag, listDegree, Max[VertexDegree[g]]][[1]]; 
 aM = AdjacencyMatrix[g]; vLM = aM[[VertexIndex[g, nodeMaxDegree]]]; 
 nN = Pick[punchingBag, vLM, 0];
 ]
vl = VertexList[g]
```

Another (probably better) solution would be to use `` Developer`ToPackedArray `` on `VertexList[g]`, this avoids the strange behaviour from occurring altogether.

Comment: There are alternatives to the Pick function to do the same job (in this case find all the vertices that aren't neighbor to a given vertex?)?

Comment: @AdamReith sure! Also you can probably prevent the error altogether. One moment