# Using Cases to pick out entries of a SparseArray

Tags: pattern-matching, sparse-arrays

I'm trying to use a `SparseArray` for some large homological algebra calculations.  I'd like to find indices of a `SparseArray` whose entries are equal to 1.  If I were operating naively on the `ArrayRules` version of the array, I'd just need do something like `Cases[sparserules, HoldPattern[_List -> 1]]` and that would give me what I want.  (FWIW: here's [why you need the HoldPattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112333/pattern-matching-for-rules).)

If it helps, I am also happy with just being able to pull off one such element at a time - `Cases[sparserules, HoldPattern[_List -> 1], All, 1]` does what I want on `ArrayRules` output.  The order is not important - if this returns a random entry that's equal to 1, that's also fine by me.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work on `SparseArray` objects, and I don't want to be packing and unpacking `SparseArray`s all the time.  Is there an efficient way to get all (or just one) indices of a `SparseArray` whose entries are equal to a given element?

Some possible starting points: [SparseArrays are atomic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13790/using-replaceall-on-sparsearray); [using Pick on SparseArrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44868/bug-with-sparsearray-selector-in-pick).  Both of these are a bit beyond my level of sophistication, however.

Comment: Is the array numeric? Then `(SparseArray[Unitize[#1 - #2], Automatic, 1]["NonzeroPositions"]) &` should fit your needs - call with array and value to index.

Comment: Ciao ciao, thanks for the tip on `"NonzeroPositions"` - that could be useful.  Unfortunately the array is not numeric - mostly polynomials, so Unitize won't work.  I like the trick, though.

Comment: @ciao Got your answer to work - I just used `Map[Boole[#===1]&, sparsearray, {2}]["NonzeroPositions"]`, which fixed the non-numeric problem.  If you put your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I presume you wrapped that `Map` in `SparseArray`? Otherwise, it's possibly not doing what you think... and even if it is, if you're going to map over the array, might as well just `MapIndexed` over it, and return the index for elements that match your tests. In any case, feel free to use the ideas in a self-answer...

Comment: In fact you don't have to wrap `Map` in `SparseArray` - it will automatically thread over `SparseArray` objects, whereas `MapIndexed` will convert them to lists.  If you want a concrete demonstration, run the following: `a = SparseArray[(# -> RandomInteger[{1, 200}]) & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 2000}, {4000, 2}]]; a1 = Map[#^2&, a, {2}]; a2 = MapIndexed[#1^2&, a, {2}];`  If you do this, `a1` will have head `SparseArray`, and the command will execute quickly.  But `a2` will take a while and have head `List`.  See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebraSparseArrays.html.

Comment: LOL - I'm not talking about the obvious - I'm talking about the results of `["NonzeroElements"]` on resultants....

Comment: OK, then I'd appreciate it if you could be more explicit about what you're talking about.  I certainly don't understand what you mean by "the results of `["NonzeroElements"]` on resultants".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a fast way if you have general values, like [@ciao's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/ciao):

```
SeedRandom[0];
sa = SparseArray[(# -> RandomChoice[Join[{x^2 + y^2, x^3}, Range@200]]) & /@ 
    RandomInteger[{1, 2000}, {4000, 2}]];

Extract[sa["NonzeroPositions"], 
  Position[sa["NonzeroValues"], x^2 + y^2, 1]] // RepeatedTiming

{0.00015,
  {{22, 1644}, {165, 37}, {207, 910}, {332, 291}, {354, 1432}, {997, 552},
   {1211, 1944}, {1240, 1514}, {1505, 1421}, {1632, 899}, {1735, 702},
   {1808, 1690}, {1816, 1445}, {1931, 1856}, {1934, 1709}, {1988, 312}}}
*)
```

If all values are numbers, then this is faster:

```
SeedRandom[0];
sa2 = SparseArray[# -> RandomInteger[{1, 200}] & /@ 
    RandomInteger[{1, 2000}, {4000, 2}]];

Pick[sa2["NonzeroPositions"], sa2["NonzeroValues"], 1] // RepeatedTiming
(*
{0.0000261,
  {{261, 1553}, {295, 1413}, {392, 1762}, {400, 1357}, {418, 850},
   {580, 237}, {665, 1699}, {739, 1314}, {776, 1589}, {874, 206}, {932, 828},
   {1215, 730}, {1636, 150}, {1770, 214}, {1815, 1922}, {1928, 676}}}
*)
```

Comment: Big +1 - that's the way to do it...

Comment: Ah, great, thanks a bunch!  I didn't know about `NonzeroValues` either - this doesn't appear to be documented.  And if I only want to pick off particular expressions one element at a time, it's just one more argument to `Position`!  I'm still curious why the `Pick` method is not faster on non-numerics, though - interesting.

Comment: @dvitek `Pick` only works when the expression tree of its second argument has the same shape as a subexpression of its first argument.  To solve the problem at hand, the second expression has to be a flat list of atomic expressions.  Try `Pick` on the first example. You'll get a semi-explanatory error message.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to be efficient, due to the `Complement`, and it's quite possible that the very first operation we do on the array "unpacks" it, but here's one possibility.

Let's suppose we have a sample array,

```
array = SparseArray@RandomInteger[{0, 5}, {10, 10}]; array // MatrixForm
```

[image]

We set a new background for this `SparseArray` by doing

```
array1 = SparseArray[array, Automatic, 1];
```

You can change `1` to whatever quantity you're looking for. This can include *expressions* like `x^2` if those are the positions you are looking for.

Then, `array1["NonzeroPositions"]` returns a `List` of the non-background positions, which is everything *but* the positions of the `1`s. We can then take the `Complement` of this list in the set of all possible position indices:

```
pos = Complement[Table[{i, j}, {i, 10}, {j, 10}]~Flatten~1, array1["NonzeroPositions"]]
(* {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {4, 10}, {5, 5}, {5, 9},
    {6, 2}, {6, 9}, {7, 3}, {7, 9}, {8, 6}, {8, 10}, {9, 7}, {10, 4}} *)
```

To verify:

```
Extract[array, array1["NonzeroPositions"]]
Extract[array, pos]
(* {4, 4, 3, 0, 5, 2, 0, 4, 2, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 3, 3, 5, 3,
    4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4,
    5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 0, 5, 0, 5, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 4,
    3, 4, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 3,
    0, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5} *)
(* {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

Comment: Hi March, this is roughly the same approach that ciao used in his comment.  There the `Unitize` has a hope of being `SparseArray`-fast.  Unfortunately for my purposes the array is far too big for `Complement` to be wieldy - this is the entire point of `SparseArray`s!

Comment: @dvitek. Right, agreed, although in defense, I was working on this solution when ciao posted his comment. As far as the `Complement` goes, I feel like there's a way to quickly "invert" the list in this case, since it's so highly structured, but off the top of my head, I can't come up with a solution.

Comment: The changing the background is a cool trick, I'll admit :).  It turns out that you can do lots of stuff that's `SparseArray`-fast - a simple `Boole[#===1]&` works for my purposes, and can also be used on expressions like `x^2`.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can do the `Complement` far more quickly by walking through the list of indices and throwing anything in that you don't see - it's all highly structured so you're golden.  But for my purposes (truly sparse arrays) it's quite slow, unfortunately.  Thanks for your help!