# How to speed up this TDSE code?

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, compile, physics

I'm trying to build a 1D time-dependent Schrodinger equation solver, using the Crank-Nicholson method. And I think the code is kind of working now, but the speed is still slow for me.

Here is the code that calculates the wave function $\psi(x,t)$ at certain time given initial wave function $\psi(x,0)$ and a position dependent potential $V(x)$.

```
TDSE1[V_Function, Ct0_, {xmin_, xmax_}, {tmin_, tmax_, dt_}] := 
 Module[{I0, Tmtx, Vmtx, Hmtx, Ct, Cls, dx, tls, xls, 
   N0Grid = Length@Ct0},
  dx = (xmax - xmin)/(N0Grid - 1);
  xls = Range[xmin, xmax, dx];
  tls = Range[tmin + 0.5 dt, tmax, dt];
  Tmtx = -(1/(2 (dx)^2))
      SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> -2, {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> 1}, {N0Grid, N0Grid}];(* kinetic energy *)
  I0 = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1.}, {N0Grid, N0Grid}]; (*identity matrix*)
  Ct = Ct0;
  Vmtx = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> V /@ xls];(*potential energy*)
  Hmtx = Tmtx + Vmtx;(*total Hamiltonian*)
  Cls = Table[
    Ct = LinearSolve[(I0 + I/2. (Hmtx)*dt), (I0 - I/2. (Hmtx)*dt).Ct]
    , {t, tls}];
  Cls
  ]
```

and here is an example of calculating a wave function using this solver

```
Ct0 = Array[Exp[-#^2] &, 400, {-10, 10}] // N;(*initial wave function*)
Cls1 = TDSE1[Function[{x}, 0.5 x^2], Ct0, {-10, 10}, {0., 50., 0.01}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{1.329230,Null}*)

ListPlot[Re[Cls1[[1 ;; 1000 ;; 100]]], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

And I'm pretty satisfied with this speed.

However, I'm more interested in a time-dependent potential, ie, $V=V(x,t)$, than a time independent one. So I changed the code a little bit so that at every time step, it recalculates the potential `Vmtx` at that time.

```
TDSE2[V_Function, Ct0_, {xmin_, xmax_}, {tmin_, tmax_, dt_}] := 
 Module[{I0, Tmtx, Vmtx, Hmtx, Ct, Cls, dx, tls, xls, 
   N0Grid = Length@Ct0},
  dx = (xmax - xmin)/(N0Grid - 1);
  xls = Range[xmin, xmax, dx];
  tls = Range[tmin + 0.5 dt, tmax, dt];
  Tmtx = -(1/(2 (dx)^2))
      SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> -2, {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> 1}, {N0Grid, N0Grid}]; 
  I0 = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1.}, {N0Grid, N0Grid}];
  Ct = Ct0;
  Cls = Table[
    Vmtx = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> (V[t] /@ xls)];
    Hmtx = Tmtx + Vmtx;
    Ct = LinearSolve[(I0 + I/2. (Hmtx)*dt), (I0 - I/2. (Hmtx)*dt).Ct]
    , {t, tls}];
  Cls
  ]
```

and the function call is also changed slitly

```
Cls2 = TDSE2[Function[{t}, Function[{x}, 0.5 x^2]], Ct0, {-10, 10}, {0., 50., 0.01}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{9.446716, Null}*)
```

but now it is about **7X slower** than before!

I tried to compile the function inside the module, replacing the `Vmtx` line by something like

```
Vmtx = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> (VCpf[t, xls])];
```

where VCpf is a compiled function defined by

```
VCpf = Compile[{{t, _Real}, {x, _Real}}, V[t][x], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
```

and that makes the problem even worse, with about **20X** slower than `TDSE1`.

**So my question is, is it possible to speed up `TDSE2` to get about the same speed as `TDSE1` or even faster?**

Comment: Your `Ct0` definition won't work for <V9, worth to add.

Comment: @Kuba I'm curious why it won't work for <v9?

Comment: @xslittlegrass To make it work on version <9, you could replace the definition of `Ct0` by this: `Ct0 = Table[Exp[-x^2], {x, -10, 10, 20/399}] // N;` (the construct where `Array` fills slots in a range `{a,b}` given by the third argument doesn't exist in earlier versions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 2 sources of inefficiency in your code. One is that you don't use the machine-precision for your `dx` (and therefore `xls`), and another one is that `Band` is not the fastest way to build a `SparseArray` object, and in the time-dependent case you have to build a new one for every time point.

Here is the code which is on the same level of performance as your time-independent code:

```
ClearAll[TDSE2];
TDSE2[V_Function, Ct0_, {xmin_, xmax_}, {tmin_, tmax_, dt_}] :=
  Module[{I0, Tmtx, Vmtx, Hmtx, Ct, Cls, dx, tls, xls, 
    N0Grid = Length@Ct0, len, ic, jr},
    dx = N@(xmax - xmin)/(N0Grid - 1);
    xls = Range[xmin, xmax, dx];
    tls = Range[tmin + 0.5 dt, tmax, dt];
    Tmtx = 
       -(1/(2 (dx)^2)) SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> -2, {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> 1}, {N0Grid, N0Grid}];
    I0 = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1.}, {N0Grid, N0Grid}];
    Ct = Ct0;
    len = Length[xls];
    ic = Prepend[Range[len], 0];
    jr = Transpose[{Range[len]}];
    Cls = 
      Table[
        Vmtx = 
           SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {len, len}, 0, {1, {ic, jr}, V[t] /@ xls}};
        Hmtx = Tmtx + Vmtx;
        Ct = LinearSolve[(I0 + I/2. (Hmtx)*dt), (I0 - I/2. (Hmtx)*dt).Ct]
        ,
        {t, tls}
      ];
    Cls
]
```

You can see that I used `dx = N@(xmax - xmin)/(N0Grid - 1);`, and also the lower-level `SparseArray` - building code

```
len = Length[xls];
ic = Prepend[Range[len], 0];
jr = Transpose[{Range[len]}];
```

and

```
SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {len, len}, 0, {1, {ic, jr}, V[t] /@ xls}};
```

See [this recent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18081/how-to-interpret-the-fullform-of-a-sparsearray/44900#44900) for an explanation of this code.

**EDIT**

As Jens pointed out in comments, an easier option than the low-level `SparseArray` construction in this particular case would be to use

```
Vmtx = DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[(V[t] /@ xls)]];
```

in place of the above 4 lines of code. This gives comparable performance, without the need to deal with low-level details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know that SparseArray object can be directly constructed.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Welcome :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin It looks like you can get the same speed by replacing your `SparseArray` construct with the simpler `Vmtx=DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[(V[t]/@xls)]]`

Comment: @Jens Thanks, I was thinking in this direction too, but did not follow this to the end. My tests show that it's a bit slower, but I will edit your suggestion in.