# How to store the nonzero elements of a sparse array in a file?

Tags: export, sparse-arrays

Often I need to use same matrix several times and for that I save them in an external file. Converting the matrix into `SparseArray` can save a lot of space in this process.

For example consider this `SparseArray`.

```
spdat = Join[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 2], {RandomReal[]}] & /@ Range[20];
spmat = SparseArray[(#[[1 ;; 2]] -> #[[3]]) & /@ spdat, {10, 10}]
```

Lets consider this `spdat`

> {{9, 10, 0.11555}, {5, 8, 0.0436915}, {6, 2, 0.376473}, {7, 10, 
>     0.893704}, {6, 3, 0.114267}, {2, 1, 0.860136}, {10, 7, 
>     0.462883}, {5, 5, 0.126532}, {9, 8, 0.327185}, {10, 3, 0.36935}, {1,
>      8, 0.98363}, {3, 3, 0.864916}, {1, 1, 0.523974}, {1, 8, 
>     0.752075}, {7, 1, 0.0122767}, {10, 4, 0.872767}, {4, 7, 
>     0.555469}, {1, 4, 0.395135}, {7, 8, 0.842624}, {7, 4, 0.943731}}

If I can `Export` this as a data file, I can create my `SparseArray` from that. A simple `Export` will export the whole matrix in dense form which will create a huge file.

If I check the `InputForm` of `spmat`, it returns,

```
InputForm[spmat]
```

> SparseArray[Automatic, {10, 10}, 0, {1, {{0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 14, 14, 16, 19}, {{1}, 
>      {4}, {8}, {1}, {3}, {7}, {5}, {8}, {2}, {3}, {1}, {4}, {8}, {10}, {8}, {10}, {3}, {4}, 
>      {7}}}, {0.5239738483968632, 0.3951345317083965, 0.9836297206953681, 0.8601364789360151, 
>     0.8649158619094384, 0.5554690352192444, 0.12653163124345568, 0.04369153890486932, 
>     0.3764726821240931, 0.11426712799092975, 0.012276677822715243, 0.9437312355928948, 
>     0.8426237324241401, 0.8937036888680452, 0.32718527756860794, 0.11555023823345034, 
>     0.36934965959862076, 0.872767483243448, 0.4628830528072616}}]

How can I retrieve `spdat` from this? Definitely the third argument contains the information about the position of nonzero elements, but I can't recognise them!

Comment: The easiest thing to do is probably to `Export` the sparse array as `.m` or `.mx` file, then you can simply `Import` it back without thinking what its pieces mean. The `.mx` file has an additional advantage that it will keep packed arrays packed. If you do want to understand the anatomy of sparse arrays, you can read e.g. [this discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18081/how-to-interpret-the-fullform-of-a-sparsearray).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin is almost certainly right, but if really want `spdat` back you can do something like `MapThread[Append, {#["NonzeroPositions"], #["NonzeroValues"]}] &@spmat`

Comment: The only thing I'll add to @LeonidShifrin's comment is that while the `.mx` format is great, it is not portable across different OS's or across different versions of MMA. I use it all the time, but this is important to keep in mind.

Comment: @march Since V10, `.mx` *is* portable across OS - but not architectures, and perhaps may not also be across different versions of Mathematica.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin. Apparently the documentation hasn't been updated, then! Both online and in my version of V10, the help files say that `.mx` was updated last at V6 and gives the caveats I gave above.

Comment: @march Yes, that's right, it hasn't been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two different ways of getting `spdat` from `spmat`:

```
Join[#[[1]], {#[[2]]}] & /@ (ArrayRules[spmat])
```

or (this is chuy's suggestion)

```
MapThread[Append, {#["NonzeroPositions"], #["NonzeroValues"]}] &@spmat
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `Export` directly "just works":

```
In[23]:= mat = SparseArray[DiagonalMatrix[2^Range[0, 10]]];

In[24]:= file = Export[CreateTemporary[], mat, "Package"];

In[25]:= FilePrint[file]

During evaluation of In[25]:=
(* Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com *)
SparseArray[Automatic, {11, 11}, 0, 
 {1, {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, 
   {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}}}, {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 
  1024}}]

In[26]:= DeleteFile[file]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sample `spdat` generated from random numbers is of course likely to be just an example for this question, but nonetheless in the interest of thoroughness I would like to point that in the literal case you cannot be sure to recover your `spdat` from `spmat`, because your `spdat` may contain **duplicate directives**, only one of which is retained when you generate the `SparseArray`.

In the example `spdat` you post, for instance, there are two conflicting directives for position {1, 8} in the resulting matrix:

```
spdat = {{9, 10, 0.11555}, {5, 8, 0.0436915}, {6, 2, 0.376473}, {7, 10, 0.893704},
  {6, 3, 0.114267}, {2, 1, 0.860136}, {10, 7, 0.462883}, {5, 5, 0.126532},
  {9, 8, 0.327185}, {10, 3, 0.36935}, 

  {1, 8, 0.98363}, (*duplicated directive*)

  {3, 3, 0.864916}, {1, 1, 0.523974}, 

  {1, 8, 0.752075}, (*duplicated directive*)

  {7, 1, 0.0122767}, {10, 4, 0.872767}, {4, 7, 0.555469}, {1, 4, 0.395135},
  {7, 8, 0.842624}, {7, 4, 0.943731}}
```

Of course, the value corresponding to one of those two directives is lost in the generation of the `SparseArray`:

```
spmat = SparseArray[(#[[1 ;; 2]] -> #[[3]]) & /@ spdat, {10, 10}];
Join[#[[1]], {#[[2]]}] & /@ (ArrayRules[spmat]);

% == spdat
(*False*)

spmat[[1, 8]]
(* 0.98363, i.e. the first value encountered in your list of rules *)
```

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB. You are right. I just want to give an example. Right way to do that would be create the positions first with `Union` and then assign the values. I am just too lazy for that :)

Comment: @Sumit Hehe, yes of course it was just an example, but I just wanted the caveat on the record for future readers :-)