# What is stored for a sparse matrix in memory?

Tags: sparse-arrays

I am wondering if a sparse matrix is stored in memory as a list which is its ArrayRules? The reason to ask this is I am trying to write a function to produce a large sparse matrix. However, I am not sure which way saves memory and is faster, return the rule to produce the sparse matrix or the sparse matrix itself?

Comment: Perhaps, try both and see which takes less memory.  Let everyone know the answer.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18081/how-to-interpret-the-fullform-of-a-sparsearray/44900#44900