# LibraryLink: Create SparseArray directly from row pointers and column indices

Tags: sparse-arrays, librarylink

In Mathematica, sparse arrays use [a CSR representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR.2C_CRS_or_Yale_format.29).  Suppose I already have data in this format.  Is there a way to create an `MSparseArray` from it directly with LibraryLink, without manually converting to `position -> value` pairs first?

This data may come from another C library that also uses CSR or CSC for its sparse matrices.

This is possible [in pure Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18081/12).  I am looking to do the same in C, with the LibraryLink API, if possible.

---

I know that there is no function to do this directly in the LibraryLink API.  What is not clear to me is whether it is reasonable to start with an empty `MSparseArray`, created using `MSparseArray_fromExplicitPositions()` (with no positions) and manually fill in the CSR data.  It is not entirely clear to me if changing the internals of an `MSparseArray` like this is allowed.