# Most efficient way to build block / banded SparseArray

Tags: performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

I have a matrix that I generate with a procedure that looks like this:

```
blaMX[ptsX_Integer, ptsY_Integer] :=
  Table[
   With[
    {
     ix = 1 + Floor[(i - 1)/(ptsY)], jx = 1 + Floor[(j - 1)/(ptsY)],
     iy = Mod[i, ptsY, 1], jy = Mod[j, ptsY, 1]
     },
    If[iy != jy,
      0,
      k1[ix, jx]
      ] +
     If[ix != jx,
      0,
      k2[iy, jy]
      ]
    ],
   {i, ptsX*ptsY},
   {j, ptsX*ptsY}
   ];
```

where I have two square matrices `k1` of dimension `ptsX` and `k2` of dimension `ptsY`

It generates a block-diagonal matrix with a bunch of block-bands. The basic structure looks like:

```
blaMX[6, 9] /. {_k1 -> 1, _k2 -> 2, c -> 3} // MatrixPlot
```

[image: basic MX]

where each of those diagonal blocks is `k2` duplicated:

```
blaMX[3, 6][[7 ;; 12, 7 ;; 12]] /. _k1 -> 0 // Grid

k2[1,1] k2[1,2] k2[1,3] k2[1,4] k2[1,5] k2[1,6]
k2[2,1] k2[2,2] k2[2,3] k2[2,4] k2[2,5] k2[2,6]
k2[3,1] k2[3,2] k2[3,3] k2[3,4] k2[3,5] k2[3,6]
k2[4,1] k2[4,2] k2[4,3] k2[4,4] k2[4,5] k2[4,6]
k2[5,1] k2[5,2] k2[5,3] k2[5,4] k2[5,5] k2[5,6]
k2[6,1] k2[6,2] k2[6,3] k2[6,4] k2[6,5] k2[6,6]
```

Each band is made up of blocks, as an unwrapping of `k1` with the [`Band`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html) starting at `{n+(i-1)*ptsY, n+(j-1)*ptsY}` being `k1[[i+1, j+1]]` (essentially just using [`Quotient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quotient.html):

```
With[{n = 1},
  Table[
   blaMX[6, 9][[
      (i - 1)*9 + n, 
      (j - 1)*9 + n
      ]] /. _k2 -> 0,
   {i, 6},
   {j, 6}
   ]
  ] // Grid
```

Now, my generation procedure is wildly inefficient. I do `ptsX^2 * ptsY^2` work, when I really only have `ptsX * ptsY * (ptsX + ptsY - 1)` (which is just `2 n^3 - n^2` if `ptsX == ptsY == n`) non-zero elements.

So, what is the best way to build a matrix of this form? My current version looks like:

```
makeKMat[k1_, k2_] :=
  With[{
    k1SparseRules =
     With[{ptsX = Length@k1, ptsY = Length@k2},
      Flatten[
       Table[
        Band[{(i - 1)*ptsY + 1, (j - 1)*ptsY + 1}, {i*ptsY, j*ptsY}] ->
         k1[[i, j]],
        {i, ptsX},
        {j, ptsX}
        ],
       1
       ]
      ],
    k2SparseRules =
     With[{ptsX = Length@k1, ptsY = Length@k2},
      {
       Band[{1, 1}] ->
        ConstantArray[k2, ptsX]
       }
      ]
    },
   With[{k3 = SparseArray[k2SparseRules]},
    SparseArray[k1SparseRules, Dimensions[k3]] + k3
    ]
   ];
```

And this works:

```
k1Pts = 6;
k2Pts = 9;
k1Test = Array[k1, {k1Pts, k1Pts}];
k2Test = Array[k2, {k2Pts, k2Pts}];
kMatTest = makeKMat[k1Test, k2Test];
kMatTest == blaMX[6, 9]

True
```

And is pretty fast, all considered:

```
k1Test2 = RandomReal[{}, {15, 15}];
k2Test2 = RandomReal[{}, {15, 15}];

{tt, mx} = makeKMat[k1Test2, k2Test2] // RepeatedTiming;
tt

0.0071

{tt2, lmx} = lazyMX[k1Test2, k2Test2] // RepeatedTiming;
tt2

0.338
```

But, I can't help but feel that this could be done more efficiently. Can someone propose a better way to build a block-banded `SparseArray` like this?

---

#### Some mild goal-post moving:

What if we wanted to extend this to an $N$-dimensional system? A way to implement this element-wise would be:

```
getCrds[i_, j_, gridDivs_] :=
  FoldList[
    With[{tot = #[[3]], new = #2},
      Append[
       Map[
        Mod[1 + Quotient[# - 1, tot], new, 1] &,
        {i, j}
        ],
       tot*new
       ]
      ] &,
    {i, j, 1},
    gridDivs
    ][[2 ;;, ;; 2]];

makeNDKMat[ks : {__List}] :=
 With[{gridDivs = Length /@ ks},
  Table[
   With[{divvy = getCrds[i, j, gridDivs]},
    Total@
     Table[
      If[AllTrue[Delete[divvy, k], Apply[Equal]],
       ks[[k, Sequence @@ divvy[[k]]]],
       0
       ],
      {k, Length@gridDivs}
      ]
    ],
   {i, Times @@ gridDivs},
   {j, Times @@ gridDivs}
   ]
  ]
```

For example, in 4D this looks like:

```
k1T = Array[k1, {2, 2}];
k2T = Array[k2, {3, 3}];
k3T = Array[k3, {4, 4}];
k4T = Array[k4, {5, 5}];
k4DLazy = 
  makeNDKMat[{k4T, k3T, k2T, k1T}] /. {_k1 -> 1, _k2 -> 2, _k3 -> 
     3, _k4 -> 4};
k4DLazy // MatrixPlot
```

[image: asdasd]

How could we efficiently build a sparse representation of this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*This* is definitely faster. It took me some time to figure out the combinatorics and there might still be some potential for improvement within the compiled functions.

```
getColumnIndices = Compile[{{m, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}, {i, _Integer}},
   Transpose[Partition[
     Partition[
      Join[
       Table[k, {k, 1, i n}],
       Flatten[Table[Table[k, {j, 1, n}], {k, i n + 1, i n + n}]],
       Table[k, {k, i n + n + 1, m n}]
       ], {1}], {n}]],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

getValues = Compile[{{k1row, _Real, 1}, {k2, _Real, 2}, {i, _Integer}},
   Block[{A},
    A = Join[
      Table[Compile`GetElement[k1row, k], {l, 1, Length[k2]}, {k, 1, i}],
      k2,
      Table[Compile`GetElement[k1row, k], {l, 1, Length[k2]}, {k, i + 2, Length[k1row]}],
      2
      ];
    Do[A[[k, k + i]] += Compile`GetElement[k1row, i + 1], {k, 1, Length[k2]}];
    A
    ],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

makeKMat3[k1_, k2_] := With[{m = Length[k1], n = Length[k2]},
  SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {m n, m n}, 0, {1, {
      Range[0, (m n ) (m + n - 1), m + n - 1],
      Flatten[getColumnIndices[m, n, Range[0, m - 1]], 2]
      },
     Flatten[getValues[k1, k2, Range[0, m - 1]]]
     }}
  ]
```

Just to give you an idea of the timings:

```
m = 100;
n = 6;
k1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, m}];
k2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
A = makeKMat2[k1, k2]; // RepeatedTiming
B = makeKMat3[k1, k2]; // RepeatedTiming
Max[Abs[A - B]]
```

> {0.11, Null}
>
> {0.000481, Null}
>
> 0.

**Addendum**

The idea for the "higher dimensional" case is similar to the idea above. I exploit that the "ColumnIndices" of the resulting matrices (when partitioned into column indices per row) stay rectangular so that column indices from the diagonal matrices can be joined to it from the left and right. Some extra index list (`diagidx`) is needed for book keeping of those column indices of the blocks that belong to the diagonal entries. All in all, only operations on the nonzero values and the column indices are performed. No `SparseArray`s are built intermediately: Even building a `SparseArray` from row pointers, column indices and nonzero values has still some considerable overhead, probably because there is a consistency checker involved in the backend. That's a pitty since I *know* that I produce consistent data. This issue is also closely related to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158413/librarylink-create-sparsearray-directly-from-row-pointers-and-column-indices) by Szabolcs.

```
getValues2 = Compile[{{k1row, _Real, 1}, {blockvals, _Real, 2}, {diagidx, _Integer, 1}, {i, _Integer}},
   Block[{A},
    A = Join[
      Table[Compile`GetElement[k1row, k], {l, 1, Dimensions[blockvals][[1]]}, {k, 1, i}],
      blockvals,
      Table[Compile`GetElement[k1row, k], {l, 1, Dimensions[blockvals][[1]]}, {k, i + 2, Length[k1row]}],
      2];
    Do[A[[k, Compile`GetElement[diagidx, k] + i]] += Compile`GetElement[k1row, i + 1], {k, 1, Length[blockvals]}];
    A
    ],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

getColumnIndices2 = Compile[{
    {blockci, _Integer, 3}, {diagci, _Integer, 
     3}, {m, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}, {i, _Integer}
    },
   If[i > 0,
    If[i < m - 1,
     Join[diagci[[All, 1 ;; i]], blockci + i n, diagci[[All, i + 1 ;; m - 1]] + (n), 2],
     Join[diagci[[All, 1 ;; i]], blockci + i n, 2]
     ],
    Join[blockci + i n, diagci[[All, i + 1 ;; m - 1]] + (n), 2]
    ],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

toSparseArrayData[b_?MatrixQ] := {
  Partition[SparseArray[b]["ColumnIndices"], Dimensions[b][[2]]],
  b,
  Dimensions[b][[2]],
  Range[Dimensions[b][[2]]]
  }

toSparseArray[X_] := 
 With[{d1 = Dimensions[X[[1]]][[1]], d2 = Dimensions[X[[1]]][[2]]},
  SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {d1, d1}, 0,
    {1, {Range[0, d1 d2, d2], Flatten[X[[1]], 1]}, Flatten[X[[2]]]}}
  ]

iteration[X_, a_] := With[{
   m = Length[a],
   blockci = X[[1]],
   blockvals = X[[2]],
   n = X[[3]],
   diagidx = X[[4]]
   },
  With[{ran = Range[0, m - 1]},
   {
    Join @@ getColumnIndices2[blockci, Transpose[Partition[Partition[Range[(m - 1) n], 1], n]], m, n, ran],
    Join @@ getValues2[a, blockvals, diagidx, ran],
    m n,
    Join @@ Outer[Plus, ran, diagidx]
    }
   ]
  ]

makeKMat3ND[ks : {__List}] := 
 toSparseArray[Fold[iteration, toSparseArrayData[ks[[1]]], Rest[ks]]]
```

Usage example and timing test:

```
SeedRandom[123];
ks = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {RandomInteger[{3, 8}]}[[{1, 1}]]], 6];
A = makeKMat2ND[Reverse@ks]; // AbsoluteTiming
B = makeKMat3ND[ks]; // AbsoluteTiming
Max[Abs[A - B]]
```

> {24.0011, Null}
>
> {0.038756, Null}
>
> 8.88178*10^-16

This is the sparsity pattern of the resulting matrix:

[image]

Comment: Wow. Honestly just wow.

Comment: This is great work ++1

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thank you very much for the bounty! May I ask where this sort of "fractal" iterations get applied?

Comment: It pops up in a specific version of [discrete variable representation](http://xbeams.chem.yale.edu/~batista/v572/ColbertMiller.pdf). This is the type of process you use for building the kinetic energy term in multiple dimensions for a direct product basis (which leads to a representation that is diagonal in the different coordinates, hence block-banded in the way I presented).

Comment: This is only slightly slower than your `getColumnIndices[]`, but it's interesting nevertheless: `SetAttributes[getColumnIndices, Listable];
getColumnIndices[m_, n_, i_] := Flatten[Partition[{Join[Table[k, {k, i n}], Flatten[Table[k, {k, i n + 1, i n + n}, {n}]], Table[k, {k, i n + n + 1, m n}]]}, {1, n}], {{4}, {2, 1}, {3}}]`

Comment: @J.M. Interesting: I've never thought of using `Flatten` to transpose an array (but it's probably better to use `Tranpose`). The major problem with this approach seems to be the performance of `Partition[{array}, {1, n}]` vs. `Partition[Partition[array, 1], n]`. Although both leave internal data of the arrays in the same ordering, the former is still considerably slower. One reason is that it unpacks (which can be remedied to some extend by using ``Partition[Developer`ToPackedArray@{array}, {1, n}]``. The other reason must be a suboptimal implementation of  `Partition`...

Comment: Yeah, [generalized `Flatten[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119/)'s ability to both flatten and transpose is convenient, but it isn't compilable sadly. That's another reason why my version is slower. I hadn't thought about packing when I wrote that snippet, but it makes sense that it would also cause slowdown.

Comment: Reminds me of [link](https://colinmorris.github.io/SongSim/#/about)

Comment: I just realized this is a perfect answer to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171918/how-can-i-compute-a-kronecker-sum-in-mathematica Do you want to link it there?

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks for the hint. But after some testing, I found out that MarcoB's answer there (which is actually the same J.M.'s answer here) is usually a bit more performant.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Interesting. I found the opposite on some tests derived from my own use case. I wonder why that is.

Answer (score 13):

Not faster, but maybe easier to implement

```
makeKMat2[k1_, k2_] := Module[{A, m, n},
  m = Length[k1];
  n = Length[k2];
  A = Map[SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> #, {n, n}, 0.] &, k1, {2}];
  With[{B = SparseArray@k2}, Do[A[[i, i]] += B, {i, 1, m}]];
  ArrayFlatten[A]
  ]
```

Your implementation needs about `0.0048`s; mine needs `0.0051`s on my machine.

(*b3m2a1 comment*)
Note that this has a simple extension to the N-dimensional case:

```
makeKMat2ND[ks : {__List}] := Fold[makeKMat2, ks]
```

Comment: Very nice. I'm gonna be sharing this code with others so the easier it is to read for people without Mathematica experience the better.

Comment: Good to hear! I was also tempted to compute the `"ColumnIndices"` and `"RowPointers"` of the resulting matrix by hand since building from the ["FullForm"  of the matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18081/how-to-interpret-the-fullform-of-a-sparsearray) is usually much faster than letting Mathematica assemble it. But I am somewhat relieved that I don't have to do that. Although it should not be too complicated as each row has the same number of entries...

Comment: One difficulty, how can I keep make sure to keep the entire thing as a `SparseArray`? If I feed it: `makeKMat2[RandomReal[{}, {10, 10}], RandomReal[{}, {10, 10}]]` it unwraps to a `List` for me, presumably owing to some auto-determined memory optimization, while if I feed it more regular data: ``makeKMat2[Table[i + j, {i, 10}, {j, 10}], 
 Table[i + j, {i, 10}, {j, 10}]]`` it's happy to keep it `Sparse`. This becomes more of a problem as I move to 4D and beyond, which I was hoping I could do recursively with this.

Comment: When using `ArrayFlatten` it is important that all occuring `SparseArray` have the same `"Background"` (aka. as default values). When casting dense, real matrices to sparse ones by applying `SparseArray` to them, the `"Background"` is automatically set to `0.` (machine precision) while building sparse arrays with the constructor have `0` as background by default. Adding `,0.` as last argument to `SparseArray` cures this. I also edited the post.

Comment: Moreover: Feel free to add as much information as other users might find useful.

Comment: Ah, now I know what you mean. Nice!

Answer (score 6):

This is slightly faster and certainly more compact than the uncompiled implementation in Henrik's answer:

```
makeKMat[k1_?SquareMatrixQ, k2_?SquareMatrixQ] := Module[{m = Length[k1], n = Length[k2]},
    KroneckerProduct[k1, IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray]] + 
    KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[m, SparseArray], k2]]
```

and as b3m2a1 notes, the extension can be done as

```
makeKMatND[ks : {__?SquareMatrixQ}] := Fold[makeKMat[#2, #1] &, ks]
```

Using the examples in the OP:

```
MatrixPlot[makeKMat[ConstantArray[1, {9, 9}], ConstantArray[2, {6, 6}]]]
```

[image: matrix plot of 2D case]

```
AbsoluteTiming[tst =
               makeKMatND[{ConstantArray[4, {5, 5}], ConstantArray[3, {4, 4}],
                           ConstantArray[2, {3, 3}], ConstantArray[1, {2, 2}]}];][[1]]
   0.000406914

MatrixPlot[tst, MaxPlotPoints -> Infinity]
```

[image: matrix plot of 4D case]

Comment: +1 for SquareMatrixQ. I did not know that it existed! And for the `KroneckerProduct` trick. I learnt it from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164895/creating-large-matrices-from-sub-blocks/166510#166510) several days later and I was _really_ suprised that it worked so well.

Comment: By sheer chance, I was rereading [Van Loan's paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0377-0427(00)00393-9) when I came across this old question... :D

Comment: Wow, thanks! That's a nice overview on Kronecker products. This will turn out very useful one day!

Comment: Very cool! I had never heard of a Kronecker product (being a chemist who masquerades as a mathematician). Very cool to know that this type of operation has a full calculus behind it (and fun to see that this matrix built from Kronecker deltas is called a Kronecker product).

Comment: @b3m2a1 I'm a chemist pretending to be a mathematician (with varying degrees of success); to be perfectly fair, I didn't learn about Kronecker products until I was well out of school. ;)