# How can I compute a Kronecker sum in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix, summation

There is Kronecker product but there is no Kronecker sum? It seems like a very important features to include.

So in the absence of a Kronecker sum function, how can I construct my own Kronecker sum $A\oplus B$ of two arbitrary $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Your question seems ambiguous. The [matrix direct sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixDirectSum.html) and [the Kronecker sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerSum.html) are two different things. Which one do you want?

Comment: @MarcoB you're absolutely right, I mean the Kronecker sum

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. You got both answers at this point anyway :-) , but it may still be best to clear that up in the text of the question.

Comment: @MarcoB That's great because I actually needed both.

Comment: See also Henrik's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165873/most-efficient-way-to-build-block-banded-sparsearray). I didn't realize I was trying to get the Kronecker sum, but he wrote an amazing compiled implementation for sparse matrices.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the [Wikipedia definition of Kronecker sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Kronecker_sum), it seems that we can define it in terms of the Kronecker products, which is built in:

```
Clear[kroneckersum]
kroneckersum[a_, b_ /; Dimensions[a] == Dimensions[b]] :=
 KroneckerProduct[a, IdentityMatrix[Length[a]]] + 
  KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[Length[b]], b]

a = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5, 5}]
b = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5, 5}]

kroneckersum[a, b]
```

---

An alternative implementation that has the significant advantage of retaining the use of `SparseArrays` for large matrices was proposed by [Henrik](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38178/henrik-schumacher) in [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171918/how-can-i-compute-a-kronecker-sum-in-mathematica/171920?noredirect=1#comment451546_171920):

```
kroneckersum[a_?SquareMatrixQ, b_?SquareMatrixQ] :=
 KroneckerProduct[a, IdentityMatrix[Length[b], SparseArray]] +
  KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[Length[a], SparseArray], b]
```

This also reminded me of [`SquareMatrixQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SquareMatrixQ.html), a convenient bit of syntactic sugar which I'd seen used before, but keep forgetting.

Comment: I think there is no reason for checking dimensions if you use `kroneckersum[a_?SquareMatrixQ, b_?SquareMatrixQ] :=
 
 KroneckerProduct[a, IdentityMatrix[Length[b], SparseArray]] + 
  KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[Length[a], SparseArray], b]
`. Due to using `SparseArray`s, this works also for larger matrices (e.g., I tested `a = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {250, 250}];
b = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {350, 350}];`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher That's very nice! I particularly like the `SparseArray` part. Would you mind if I added / edited your method in the answer?

Comment: Of course I don't mind. That was the purpose of my comment.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

You could use [`DiagonalMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiagonalMatrix) and [`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten) to define a direct sum:

```
DirectSum[a_List] := ArrayFlatten @ Block[{Identity}, DiagonalMatrix[Identity/@a]]
```

For instance:

```
DirectSum[{
    {{a,b,c},{d,e,f}},
    {{g,h},{i,j},{k,l}}
}] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  a & b & c & 0 & 0 \\
>  d & e & f & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & g & h \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & i & j \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & k & l \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

See @MarcoB's answer if you wanted the Kronecker sum.

Answer (score 8):

From the docs for [`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct.html):

> ```
> KroneckerSum[a_, b_] /; MatrixQ[a] && MatrixQ[b] :=
>   Catch@Module[{n, p, m, q},
>     {n, p} = Dimensions[a]; {m, q} = Dimensions[b];
>     If[n != p || m != q, Throw[$Failed]];
>     KroneckerProduct[a, IdentityMatrix[m]] +
>      KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[n], b]
>     ];
> ```