# SparseArray to list of lists (column entries) efficiently?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, sparse-arrays, gathering

Suppose we have a very big very sparse matrix, e.g.:

```
m=10^5; n=10^5; r=10^6; a =SparseArray[Transpose[{RandomInteger[{1,m},r],RandomInteger[{1,n},r]}]->RandomChoice[{-1,1,2,-3},r],{m,n}]
```

How can I efficiently transform a `SparseArray` (which is in the [CRS format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format))) into the [list of lists format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#List_of_lists_(LIL)), i.e. a table, which contains in the i-th place all entries of the i-th column? One solution is:

```
Table[{#[[1,1]],#[[2]]}& /@ ArrayRules[a[[All,v]]][[;;-2]],{v,Dimensions[a][[2]]}]
```

This is way too slow. Another solution (which I copied from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/178711/sparsearray-accesing-nonzero-row-and-column-entries) and don't understand), is:

```
Module[{b=Transpose[a],ci,rp,v,l1,l2}, ci=b["ColumnIndices"]; rp=b["RowPointers"]; v=b["NonzeroValues"]; 
 l1 = Internal`PartitionRagged[Flatten[ci], Differences[rp]];   
 l2 = Internal`PartitionRagged[v, Differences[rp]];   
 Table[ Transpose[{l1[[j]],l2[[j]]}], {j,Length@l1}]]
```

This is slow as well. A third attempt:

```
Module[{l=GatherBy[Sort@Transpose@Join[Reverse@Transpose@a["NonzeroPositions"],{a["NonzeroValues"]}],First]},   
  l=AssociationThread[Map[First,l,2],Map[Rest,l,{2}]];  Table[Lookup[l,j,{}],{j,Dimensions[a][[2]]}]];
```

This is very fast, but it constructs an `Association`, which eats up a lot of RAM. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you need the ListOfLists format? Is it for export? I ask because perhaps there might be more efficient methods than converting to an explicit list.

Comment: @MarcoB Not for export, I need LOL in an efficient-to-be algorithm, in which I search for paths in a bipartite acyclic directed graph with weighted edges. The mentioned LOL represents the edges of the graph.

Comment: I modified the third one to avoid associations: `Block[{pos, id, l, nu}, pos = a["NonzeroPositions"]; l = GatherBy[Sort[MapThread[Append, {Reverse[pos, 2], a["NonzeroValues"]}]], First]; nu = Transpose[{Complement[Range[Last[Dimensions[a]]], a["NonzeroPositions"][[All, 2]]]}];
 Insert[Drop[#, None, 1] & /@ l, {}, nu]]`. Please test it against your actual application.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you! For a $10^6\times10^6$ matrix with $10^7$ nonzero entries, it needs 20seconds and 3GB RAM, an improvement!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
result = With[{b = Transpose[a]},
     Internal`PartitionRagged[
      Transpose[{Flatten[b["ColumnIndices"]], b["NonzeroValues"]}],
      Differences[b["RowPointers"]]
      ]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.074976

This is only difference from the second code snippet that you posted: `` Internal`PartitionRagged `` is performed only once and in the very end. This allows us to skip `Table` (slow!) and to reduce the amount of operations on ragged lists.

How does this work? First of all, LOL is a column-major format while CRS is row-major. That is why we transpose in the beginning to obtain a matrix `b`. The CRS is such that `b["ColumnIndices"]` stores all the $j$-indices from the array rules `{i,j} -> v` of `b` in row major order in a single flat list. (That corresponds to the `i`-indices of `a`.) The according nonzero values are stored in `b["NonzeroValues"]` in the same order. So `Transpose[{Flatten[b["ColumnIndices"]], b["NonzeroValues"]}]` contains the LOL data, but flattened out by one level. The row pointers in `b["RowPointers"]` tell one where to break this list apart to obtain the lists for each row: The $k$-th row of `b` has `Differences[b["RowPointers"]][[k]]` entries. And the actual chopping can be performed with `` Internal`PartitionRagged ``; it is a specialized and thus faster variant of `TakeList`. (Actually, it is vice versa: `TakeList` is a generalized but slower version of `` Internal`PartitionRagged ``. The former was introduced in version 11.2 while the latter has been around in the system for quite some time before.)

Comment: Dear @Henrik, thank you! As always, your code is incredibly efficient! Thumbs up also for the explanation! I might have questions later on : ).

Comment: Thank you for your compliment. Always glad to be of help.