# SparseArray row operations

Tags: sparse-arrays, performance-tuning

Given a large (very) sparse matrix, A, how can I efficiently "operate" on only the nonzeros in a given row? For example: For each row in A, generate a list of column indices that have a magnitude (absolute value) greater than a threshold, r.

My current approach is similar in spirit to a previous answer by Leonid ([Efficient way to combine SparseArray objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276/efficient-way-to-combine-sparsearray-objects/287#287)). I shamelessly steal his implementation of `spart`.

**My current approach**

First, let's build a random `SparseArray` for testing purposes.

```
randomSparseArray[n_Integer, r_Integer] := SparseArray[
  Table[{Random[Integer, {1, n}], Random[Integer, {1, n}]} ->RandomReal[],{r}]
,{n, n}];

A = randomSparseArray[10, 20]; (*10x10 matrix with 20 nonzeros*)
```

When `Part` is used to grab a row of `A`, a `SparseArray` representation is returned. Okay so let's rip this representation apart into its raw form using `spart`. For example the 3rd row of `A`

```
HoldPattern[spart[SparseArray[s___], p_]] := {s}[[p]];    
raw = spart[A[[3]], 4];
(*{1, {{0, 2}, {{10}, {5}}}, {0.534313, 0.981372}}*)
```

And then use a combination of `Part` and `Position` to extract the column indices from `raw` . (here I use a threshold of 0.5)

```
ind = Flatten@Position[Flatten@raw[[3]],x_/;Abs[x]>0.5];
Flatten[raw[[2, 2]]][[ind]]
```

Wrapping this all up into a function:

```
thresholdIndex[A_SparseArray, r_] := Module[{raw, ind},
raw = spart[A, 4];
ind = Flatten@Position[Flatten@raw[[3]], x_ /; Abs[x] > r];
Flatten[raw[[2, 2]]][[ind]]
]
```

We can now use `Map` to hit each row of `A` and search for column indices for elements with magnitudes greater than say, 0.5

```
Map[thresholdIndex[#, .5] &, A]
```

This whole process feels a little roundabout. First Mathematica has to extract a new `SparseArray` representation of a row (is this expensive?), we then chop it into pieces in order to work on it. Is there an easier way to do this while still maintaining performance?

My other idea is to apply `spart` to the original matrix and work with the CSR (compressed-sparse-row) representation. But this seems to defeat the purpose of even using a `SparseArray` from the get go.

**Sidebar**

I've been starting to implement an efficient algebraic multigrid (AMG) package in Mathematica. AMG is a fast iterative method traditionally used to solve large sparse matrix equations produced from the discretization of elliptic PDEs. One of the steps in the algorithm is very similar in flavor to `thresholdIndex`. As a sidebar, does anyone know if a nice AMG has been implemented in Mathematica? I would like to build a tool similar to PyAMG (http://code.google.com/p/pyamg/).

Answer (score 10):

When working with `SparseArray` objects you should generally try to use functions that operate on `SparseArray` objects without converting to normal form.

You can use [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnitStep.html) for threshold operations:

```
row = Range[-5, 5];
r = 2;
1 - UnitStep[r - Abs@row]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}
> ```

For position you can use reconversion with `SparseArray` and [sparse array Properties](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83721/121):

```
SparseArray[{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11}
> ```

Though not necessary in this case (as I will show) you can `Map` functions directly onto a `SparseArray` and the rows will be converted to individual `SparseArray` objects for the function.

Our function:

```
threshPos[t_] := SparseArray[1 - UnitStep[t - Abs@#]]["AdjacencyLists"] &;
```

A sample array:

```
SeedRandom[1]
sa = RandomInteger[12, {10, 10}] /. x_ /; x > 5 -> 0 // SparseArray;

sa // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Map our function:

```
threshPos[2] /@ sa
```

> ```
> {{2,10}, {4,8}, {7,9,10}, {1,4,5,6,8}, {1,4,6,9}, {3,4,6}, {9}, {3}, {6}, {3,4,8,9}}
> ```

In this case however we can operate on the entire array at once for increased performance, as `"AdjacencyLists"` conveniently returns exactly what you want:

```
threshPos[2] @ sa
```

> ```
> {{2,10}, {4,8}, {7,9,10}, {1,4,5,6,8}, {1,4,6,9}, {3,4,6}, {9}, {3}, {6}, {3,4,8,9}}
> ```

Timings on a larger array:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

sa = RandomInteger[25, {500, 500}] /. x_ /; x > 5 -> 0 // SparseArray;

threshPos[2] /@ sa // timeAvg
threshPos[2] @ sa  // timeAvg
```

> 0.010112
>
> 0.0009232

Comment: Big +1. I wanted to write up something like this but did not have the time. Folks, not enough love for this answer!

Comment: @Leonid Thanks a lot; I'll treasure that. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Great! This is a very slick answer. `"AdjacencyList"` is a nice hidden gem. I'll be using that trick quite a lot more.

Comment: @leibs I'm glad you like it.  I had forgotten `Abs` in the function definition but that's corrected.  Speaking of which don't forget the second "s" in `"AdjacencyLists"`.

Comment: @leibs a number of of the opaque objects in mma have properties. Another good one: [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html).

Comment: I think `Clip[Abs@data, {r+1, r}, {0, 1}]` provides a noticeable speed up compared to `1 - UnitStep[r - Abs@data]`

Comment: @CarlWoll I don't find those operations to be equivalent?  I'm doing e.g. `r = 2;
data = {-2.28, -2.88, -1.77, 3.6, 1.38, -3.57, 2.07, 2.85, 0.54, -2.43};` then `Clip[Abs@data, {r + 1, r}, {0, 1}]` and `1 - UnitStep[r - Abs@data]` and getting different results.  Am I doing it wrong?  By the way for performance I would in practice be using `Subtract` rather than `-` due to [(40927)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/121).

Comment: I was assuming integer data. For real data, you could use `Clip[Abs@data, {r+$MachineEpsilon, r}, {0, 1}]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Ah, I see.  Thanks for the pro tip! :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think that you on the right way, but you can do some improvements.

First of all, this matrix generation is much more efficient:

```
randomSparseArray[n_Integer, m_Integer] := 
 SparseArray[RandomInteger[{1, n}, {m, 2}] -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, m]];

A = randomSparseArray[10, 20];
```

You can extract nonzero values and their positions by

```
A["NonzeroValues"]
A["NonzeroPositions"]
```

> {0.169243, 0.397281, 0.907845, 0.572137, 0.0948881, 0.603708, 0.6843, 
>   0.375677, 0.548642, 0.896008, 0.654598, 0.59134, 0.991824, 0.37921, 
>   0.944823, 0.431562, 0.0285837, 0.330543, 0.82086}
>
> {{1, 1}, {1, 9}, {1, 5}, {1, 10}, {2, 1}, {2, 5}, {5, 10}, {5, 2}, {6,
>      10}, {6, 6}, {6, 5}, {6, 2}, {7, 10}, {7, 6}, {7, 7}, {8, 4}, {9, 
>     5}, {9, 4}, {10, 9}}

Or you can see how Mathematica stores SparseArray

```
?A
```

[image]

and use Leonid Shifrin's `spart` to extract this information

```
HoldPattern[spart[SparseArray[s___], p_]] := {s}[[p]];  
spart[A, 4]
```

> {1, {{0, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8, 12, 15, 16, 18, 
>      19}, {{1}, {9}, {5}, {10}, {1}, {5}, {10}, {2}, {10}, {6}, {5}, \
>   {2}, {10}, {6}, {7}, {4}, {5}, {4}, {9}}}, {0.169243, 0.397281, 
>     0.907845, 0.572137, 0.0948881, 0.603708, 0.6843, 0.375677, 0.548642,
>      0.896008, 0.654598, 0.59134, 0.991824, 0.37921, 0.944823, 0.431562,
>      0.0285837, 0.330543, 0.82086}}

If you want just to pick elements with large magnitudes you can simply run

```
B = Chop[A, 0.5];
```

Extracting of row can be done as follows

```
pos = spart[A, 4][[2, 1]];
val = spart[A, 4][[3]];
col = spart[A, 4][[2, 2, All, 1]];

rowval = val[[1 + pos[[#]] ;; pos[[# + 1]]]] &[100]; (* nonzero values in row 100 *)
rowpos = col[[1 + pos[[#]] ;; pos[[# + 1]]]] &[100]; (* nonzero positions in row 100 *)
```

Note, that it is much faster, then `A[[100]]['NonzeroPosition']` and `spart[A[[100]],4]` because computation of `A[[100]]` takes a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I didn't know about the short hand for "NonzeroValues". Where is this documented? I've been looking for that feature for a while in a different application.

Comment: @leibs I don't know where this is documented but you can run `PropertyList[A]` and see these options. First time I found these options here on StackEchange.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps defeating the point of `SparseArray`:

```
threshold[A_,u_]:=Position[Normal@A,_?(#>u&)]
```

will return position from SparseArray A of entries > u.