# Additive SparseArray Assembly

Tags: performance-tuning, sparse-arrays, expression-construction

The goal is to assemble a `SparseArray` in an additive fashion.

Let us assume we have a large `List` of indices (some will be repeated). We generate a simple test list of indices and values

```
ind = RandomInteger[{1, 4}, {10, 2}];
val = RandomReal[{-1,1}, Length[ind]];
```

where each value corresponds to an index from `ind`. I would like to build a `SparseArray` in a way such that the repeated index values are summed into the array.

If we simply use:

```
SparseArray[ind -> val, {4,4}]
```

only the first index encounter is written into the `SparseArray`, all repeated indices are ignored.

**Current Solution (slow + ugly)**

This solution is slow and is only shown to make precise what exactly I am trying to accomplish. We pre-allocate a sparse array of the correct size and use `Do` to accumulate the values at each index:

```
n = 5;
ind = RandomInteger[{1, n}, {3*n, 2}];
val = RandomReal[{1, 1}, Length[ind]];
A = SparseArray[{1, 1} -> 0, {n, n}];
Do[
   A[[Sequence @@ ind[[i]]]] += val[[i]]
,{i, 1, Length[val]}
]
```

There are some great tips on working with `SparseArrays`  in [Efficient by-element updates to SparseArrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/777/efficient-by-element-updates-to-sparsearrays) and [SparseArray row operations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31908/sparsearray-row-operations). A clever combination of `GatherBy`, `Sort`, etc. operations on `ind` and `val` may be good path to head down. I just can't see it yet.

Comment: I just was about to post a new question asking this same thing when I came across your question. Thanks, leibs and Mr.Wizard!

Comment: Related: [(17734)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17734/121)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is actually an undocumented System Option that tells *Mathematica* to do this automatically.  The default behavior:

```
ind = {{3, 1}, {3, 3}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}};
val = {1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1};

SparseArray[ind -> val] // Grid
```

$
\begin{matrix}
 0 & 0 & 3 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 3 & 1
\end{matrix}
$

Now with our "magic" Option ([learned from Oliver Ruebenkoenig](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00335.html)):

```
SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}];
(* equivalently:
   SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}] *)
SparseArray[ind -> val] // Grid
```

$
\begin{matrix}
 0 & 0 & 4 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 6 & 6 & 2
\end{matrix}
$

Arbitrary functions are accepted by version 9 and later; see: [Optimising 2D binning code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17734/optimising-2d-binning-code/17742#17742)

```
SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> (# - +##2 &)}];

SparseArray[ind -> val] // Grid
```

$\begin{matrix}
 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -4 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}$

To restore the default behavior set:

```
SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 0}];
(* equivalently:
   SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> First}] *)
```

To encapsulate this setting, use `` Internal`WithLocalSettings ``: [SetOptions locally?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136005/setoptions-locally/136017#136017)

Comment: Another reference for "TreatRepeatedEntries": [What are some useful, undocumented Mathematica functions?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/807)

Comment: @MichaelE2 What a gem. I never would have found that. @Mr.Wizard Any hidden `SparseArray` tricks for setting all values in a row to zero except the diagonal, which should be set to one.

Comment: As far as zeroing a row, I found that I can just take the `SparseArray`, `A` and indices of zero rows `rows` and set `A[[rows,All]] = 0.0'. Adding `1` back to the diagonal of the deleted rows can be done with `A = A + SparseArray[Thread[{#, #} &[rows]] -> ConstantArray[1.0, Length[rows]],{nDOF, nDOF}, 0.0];` Where `nDOF` is the dimension of `A`.

Answer (score 7):

```
n=4;    
ind = RandomInteger[{1, n}, {10, 2}]
val = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Length[ind]]

#[[1, 1]] -> Total[#[[;; , 2]]] & /@ GatherBy[Thread[{ind, val}], First]

a = SparseArray[%, {n, n}]
```

or quite ugly but compact:

```
b = SparseArray[#, {n, n}] & /@ Thread[ind -> val] // Total

a == b
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Also possible :`(#[[1, 1]] -> Total[#[[;; , 2]]]) & /@ 
  GatherBy[Thread[{ind, val}], First]`

Comment: @andre good point, should be faster.

Comment: Great solutions. The second method `SparseArray[#, {n, n}] & /@ Thread[ind -> val] // Total` seems to really hang. The first listed and the solution by @andre are both very fast. THANKS!