# Add values from a list, at positions from a list, to a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I'm investigating matrix assembly and one of the things I'm trying to do is add specific values to a larger matrix based on a list which is essentially defining connectivity of nodes.

For example:
Start with a null matrix, for this example a 6x6 will be selected.

```
m=ConstantArray[0, {6, 6}]
```

If I want to add 2 to the value at position {3,4} I can use the following code.

```
m=ReplacePart[m, {3, 4} -> (Part[m, 3, 4] + 2)]
```

What I would like to do is feed this process via lists though.
Creating a list of values to be added.

```
v={{2},{3},{4}}
```

Creating a list of locations to add these values.

```
locs = {{1, 2},{1,3},{1,4}}
```

Combining these two lists so that it gives {value, loc} as a new list

```
comb = Partition[Flatten[Riffle[v, locs]], 3]
```

Trying to map this new list comb across the matrix m using ReplacePart

```
f = ReplacePart[m,{#[[2]], #[[3]]} -> (Part[m, #[[2]], #[[3]]] + #[[1]])] & /@ comb
```

If my feeder list (comb) only have a single entry, the code runs, but I get an extra level added to m, which I can Flatten out afterwards.

**EDIT** Values may be added to the same location several times and so methods need to keep a running total.

However, once I get two or more entries to my feeder list I get a new matrix for each iteration, which makes sense but not what I want.

I'm missing something here as it's creating a new entry for each time the list is mapped across.  When the intention is to add the values in the list to the existing values at a certain position and return the new updated matrix.

I'm guessing to get a single matrix with all of the values added to the exising values will need an approach that writes the new matrix to m before running the next element in the list.  Perhaps using something similar to a Do or maybe Module (which are a complete mystery to me).

I'm hoping my code and description is clear and that I'm not too far away from a working solution.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(37566)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37566/121)

Comment: I think the question that you've linked to provides a solution to the question that I've asked, however the methods provided are specific ONLY for SparseArray (a function I was unaware of yesterday).  The answers to my question have shown several different ways of achieving the same behaviour as my question was not function specific.  I personally find the answers to my question to be broad and show comparisons between methods and style which has to be positive for someone learning Mathematica by creating behaviour using several different methods.  Please can you reopen.

Comment: Are you aware that you can convert a `SparseArray` to a standard array (nested `List`) using `Normal`?

Comment: No, every day is a school day, thanks for the pointer...   I'm going to have a busy afternoon working through and deconstructing all of the solutions below.  I'm genuinely grateful for them it's given me a lot to think about and tinker with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Untested, so CW)

Consider using `MapThread[]` along with `ReplacePart[]`:

```
MapThread[ReplacePart[m, #1 :> Extract[m, #1] + #2] &, {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}, {2, 3, 4}}]
```

---

Another possibility involves the use of `SparseArray[]`:

```
SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}];
pos = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}};
add = {2, 3, 4};
m + SparseArray[Thread[pos -> add], Dimensions[m]]
```

The little piece of black magic on top is needed if you have repeated entries in `pos`; this will add up the corresponding entries together.

Comment: That's the way to do it... +uno

Comment: That's very neat, I never would have come up with this in a thousand years.  Thank you.  I'll leave it a few days before accepting any solutions though to maintain interest.

Comment: This "*Mathematica* Gedanken Edition" is very difficult to use, admittedly. More seriously, I'm glad to hear that it works. :)

Comment: @J. M. That's plagiarism. _"Mathematica Gedanken Edition"_ is trademarked

Comment: @bel, uff, you're right. Who's holding the trademark now? ;)

Comment: @J. M. Guess who? :)

Comment: @bel, BTW, who's handling customer complaints for that? The interface is really not the best… ;P

Comment: @J. M. You surely have the _"Student Gedanken Edition"_. You should upgrade to the _NKGW_ (namely _"New Kind of Gedanken Workbench"_)  which provides many of the new Lotus-123 and WordPerfect enhancements, including copy-paste and  automatic line numbering.

Comment: The first one needs to be : `( m=ReplacePart [m.. ] ) &`  (It is a good bit slower than any of the `SparseArray` approaches anyway.. )

Comment: @george, posted the first part before learning OP's requirement of adding entries in dupe positions. Had something like `Fold[]` in mind, but I guess the overwriting approach is more expedient.

Answer (score 4):

The `"TreatRepeatedEntries"` method may be impossible to beat but the more mundane method is to use [`AddTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AddTo.html).  Starting with the definitions in your question:

```
v = {{2}, {3}, {4}};

locs = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}};

m = ConstantArray[0, {6, 6}];

comb = Partition[Flatten[Riffle[v, locs]], 3];
```

We need merely:

```
m[[##2]] += # & @@@ comb;
```

Now:

```
m
```

> ```
> {{0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0},
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
>  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
> ```

Comment: SA *can* be beat handily so long as cardinality of changes is not *too* crazy.... and +1 on the shorty...

Comment: @ciao Interesting.  I think when working on problems like [(8178714)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8178714/121) I found `"TreatRepeatedEntries"` faster than any other (non-compiled) method I tried.  Could you give an example?  Or better yet post an answer with your method and timings?  (Oh, and thanks.)

Comment: Sure - I cobbled it up when I saw question as throw-away, s/b easy to recreate, will do in next 24 or so (and test to verify the Q&D result) - basically I'd linearized the indices, gathered, totaled that, then fed as an AddTo, then reshaped... stay tuned

Comment: @Mr.Wizard neat and +1..."TreatRepeatedEntires" was another of the wonderful new things like `PartitionMap`...obviously I make comments about efficiency...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: umm, let's chalk this up to shooting my mouth off early - re-did from memory my method, it behaves similarly to your neat short answer: it can beat SA when number of changes is relatively small (so overhead of SA creation takes its toll), and slower when cardinality high, with the downside of unnecessary verbosity of code - not worth posting (*unless I can figure out how to beat `GatherBy `'s functionlaity*)

Answer (score 3):

put all your added values in a sparse array of same dimension and add the whole matrix:

```
 m = ConstantArray[0, {6, 6}]
 v = {2, 3, 4, 6}
 locs = {{1, 2}, {3, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 2}}
```

the `GatherBy` in here is taking care of repeated positions
(Note @GuessWhoItIs shows a cleaner approach , this does not rely on remembering an undocumented system option however.. )

```
 m + SparseArray[#[[1, 1]] -> Total[#[[All, 2 ]]] & /@ 
     GatherBy[ Transpose[{locs, v}] , #[[1]] & ], 
     Dimensions@m] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

just this if you know you don't repeat positions:

```
 m + SparseArray[Rule @@@ Transpose[{locs, v}], Dimensions@m];
```

Comment: I was about to post something similar. +1 If you migrate the list of locs and v's out of the sparse array you can handle repeat positions. `m = m + Total[
   SparseArray[#1 -> #2, Dimensions[m]] & @@@ Transpose@{locs, v}]` at the cost of some overhead with multiple sparse arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
m = ConstantArray[0, {6, 6}]
v = {{2}, {3}, {4}}
locs = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}
comb = Partition[Flatten[Riffle[v, locs]], 3]

result = Fold[
             ReplacePart[#1, {#2[[2]], #2[[3]]} -> 
                  Part[#1, #2[[2]], #2[[3]]] + #2[[1]]] & , m, comb]
```

> ```
> {{0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},   
>    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
> ```

Positions might be duplicated.
For example with `locs={{1,2},{1,2},{1,2}}` and `v = {{2}, {3}, {4}}`it gives the total 2+3+4 at position {1,2} :

> ```
> {{0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, if the locs are all duplicates, say {{1,2},{1,2},{1,2}} for example, this solution returns the last value in v at the matrix location though, rather than being the sum which would be 9.  Whilst duplicate locations will be rare they still may occur and I would like to add them on to the existing value if possible.

Comment: That is a error from me: `Part[m, ...]` should be `Part[#1,...]`. I'm going to correct this error. Sorry

Comment: Error corrected !

Comment: No apology needed, thanks for taking the time to answer :)

Comment: You should add a note that positions might be duplicated to the question

Answer (score 2):

How about using `MapAt`?

```
pos = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 6}, {2, 6}};
add = {2, 3, 4, 10, 11};

Block[{i = 0, a = Reverse@add[[Ordering@pos]]}, 
 MapAt[(i++; Plus[#, a[[i]]]) &, m, pos]]
```

Not the most elegant, but seems to work well, and handles repeat indices. It seems `MapAt` does some weird ordering of the indices before applying them. Maybe the community can comment on why.