# Converting x,y pairs to an image: alternative to Histogram3D for sparse data?

Tags: plotting, image-processing

I have a list of `{x, y}` integer pairs representing single events in pixel coordinates in the `{x, y}` plane, with occasional duplicates. I'd like to convert that list into an image.  There are only a few thousand `{x,y}` pairs, but the x y space is large, 1k x 1k, so `Histogram3D[XYlist, {xpixels, ypixels}]` is very slow. Is there a simple command to convert this list into a 2d array (or an image)? 
For example, with only 4 points:

```
coords = {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {1000, 300}, {250, 300}}
Histogram3D[coords, {1000, 1000}]
```

This returns a graphical histogram after some time.  I'd like a 2d array or image. Maybe use `HistogramList` somehow?

I'm hoping there's a better way than defining a 2d constant array and looping through the list of points to populate it, incrementing the pixel value for each hit.

Comment: You want a 2D array representing the number of events at a certain pixel  `{x, y}`?

Comment: @march thank you, yes a 2D array, in this case 1000 x 1000, the value of each element representing the number of events at that pixel.  (so in this case most values would be 0).

Comment: I've got an answer for you, I think, that will be very fast. Hold on a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. We'll use as a sample list

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {1000, 2}];
```

This is a list of 1000 pixels positions, where `x` and `y` go from 1 to 100.  We first `Tally`, which counts the repeats, turn each tally into a `Rule` that we feed to `SparseArray` to generate the array, then use `ArrayPlot`. You will need to tell `SparseArray` the number of pixels in each direction. In this case, the image is 100 by 100 pixels. In your case, replace 100 by 1000 pixels.

```
ArrayPlot[SparseArray[Rule @@@ Tally@list, {100,100}]]
```

[image]

Could also use `MatrixPlot`:

```
MatrixPlot[SparseArray[Rule @@@ Tally@list, {100,100}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This works very efficiently! Excellent solution @march    It also preserves the absolute coordinates (I was worried it might shift everything so the first event moved to 0,0  ) Great!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SparseArray` directly with the option `"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1` ([ref](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37566/4678)):

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, {10000, 2}];

SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}];

s = SparseArray[
    list -> ConstantArray[1, Length@list], {1000, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.001821, Null} *)

s // ArrayPlot
```

[image]

It is the most efficient approach to obtain histogram (and weighted histogram as well) on sparse data.

Comment: Yes this is even faster and gets the intended result. (Without TreatRepeatedEntries->1 it gives a binary image; I would certainly never have stumbled across this solution!) The Stackexchange community is wonderful!