# Subtract second element of element of list from other list if the first elements are equal

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists

```
l1 = {{{1,2},1},{{3,4},2},{{1,3},3}};
l2 = {{{1,2},2},{{3,5},2},{{1,3},3}};
```

My goal is to have a function that, if the first element of an element of `l1` is the same as the first element of an element of `l2`, it has to subtract the second element of the element of `l2` to the one on `l1`. If not, just append to the list.

For example, the goal here would be to return

```
{{{1,2},-1},{{3,4},2},{{3,5},2},{{1,3},0}};
```

I do know how to do this with `for` and `while`, but I feel that that's not the mathematica way, as I want it.

**EDIT:**

The lengths of `l1` and `l2` might vary and the first pair could be any real number. The second element it is indeed a positive integer.

Comment: If `l2` contains a pair `{{a,b},c}` that `l1` has, then will it be at the same index as it is in `l1`?

Comment: @Myridium No, it won't.

Comment: @Garmekain In that case, are the `{a,b}` within each list guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: @MartinEnder There won't be any equal elements within a single list, but `{a,b}` of `l1` might appear on `l2`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one way, but it is likely not the best:

```
a1 = Rule @@@ l1;
a2 = Rule @@@ l2;

sub[{x_, y_}] := x - y
sub[{x_}] := x

Merge[{a1, a2}, sub]
(* <|{1, 2} -> -1, {3, 4} -> 2, {1, 3} -> 0, {3, 5} -> 2|> *)
```

This solution does not care about the position of elements in the two lists. It just looks for "equivalent" elements.  It also doesn't allow equivalent elements within the same list.

---

*Note: The below version is based on a misreading of the question and only compares elements that are at the same position within `l1` and `l2`.*

<del>If we want to do it precisely the way you described it</del>, we can use [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html):

```
Clear[combine]
combine[{key_, val1_}, {key_, val2_}] := {key, val1 - val2} (* same key *)    
combine[a_, b_] := Sequence[a, b] (* handle the rest of cases, i.e. different keys *)

MapThread[combine, {l1, l2}]
(* {{{1, 2}, -1}, {{3, 4}, 2}, {{3, 5}, 2}, {{1, 3}, 0}} *)
```

This only compares elements in the same position within the two lists.

If you wish to write `combine` as an inline function, you need to prevent the splicing of `Sequence` into `If` by using `Unevaluated`:

```
If[First[#1] == First[#2], 
 {First[#1], Last[#1] - Last[#2]}, 
 Unevaluated@Sequence[#1, #2]
] &
```

I used `First` and `Last` instead of `...[[1]]` and `...[[2]]` only for readability. Too many brackets tend to confuse me.

Comment: After clarification from the OP, the `MapThread` version won't work, I think.

Comment: @MartinEnder You are right. I got confused with all the "element of element of" in the title and description.

Comment: @Szabolcs. very elegant solution. Thanks for posting it. I was completely oblivious of `Merge` . +1

Answer (score 5):

For the example you gave, with positive integer pairs as the first element and no duplication:

```
l1 = {{{1,2},1},{{3,4},2},{{1,3},3}};
l2 = {{{1,2},2},{{3,5},2},{{1,3},3}};

SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Subtract}];

SparseArray[Rule @@@ Join[l1, l2]] // ArrayRules // Most

List @@@ %
```

> ```
> {{1, 2} -> -1, {1, 3} -> 0, {3, 4} -> 2, {3, 5} -> 2}
>
> {{{1, 2}, -1}, {{1, 3}, 0}, {{3, 4}, 2}, {{3, 5}, 2}}
> ```

Reference: [Additive SparseArray Assembly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37566/121)

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer, but certainly, not the most efficient.

```
{#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]] + If[Length@# == 2, #[[2, 2]], 0]} & /@ 
 GatherBy[Join[l1, 
   Table[{i[[1]], -i[[2]]}, {i, l2}]], First]
```