# faster way to merge data

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

for example I have a data

```
Clear[data];
data[n_] := 
  Join[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {n, 2}], RandomReal[1., {n, 1}], 2];
```

then `data[3]` gives

```
{{4, 8, 0.264842}, {9, 5, 0.539251}, {3, 1, 0.884612}}
```

in each sublist, first two value is matrix index, the last is **matrix element which have to be added together for same matrix index**.

I want to transform the data into matrix. Usually I do it like

```
Clear[toSparse]
toSparse[data_] := 
 SparseArray@
  Normal@Merge[Thread[data[[;; , 1 ;; 2]] -> data[[;; , -1]]], Total]
```

I cared about the performance

```
In[171]:= toSparse[data[1000]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[171]= {0.00836793, Null}

In[172]:= toSparse[data[10000]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[172]= {0.0644464, Null}

In[173]:= toSparse[data[100000]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[173]= {1.35507, Null}

In[174]:= toSparse[data[1000000]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[174]= {200.862, Null}
```

Any faster way to do this?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The question itself, that I read as "I want to transform the data into matrix. (...). Any faster way to do this?" doesn't really have anything to do with `SparseArray`s, right? So the duplicate only explains the answers given so far, that use `SparseArray`s. The reason I point out this is that there are even faster ways than the ones presented here.

Comment: @Marius I somehow read "I want to transform the data into matrix" as *I want to transform the data into a sparse array* probably because it was followed by `toSparse[data_] := . . .`.  I'll reopen.  I look forward to your answer with a faster method than `"TreatRepeatedEntries"`!

Comment: Related: [(37566)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37566/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you so much for the link : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) system options to total repeated entries instead of taking the first. Here is a function that does this:

```
carl[data_] := Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    old=SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> "TreatRepeatedEntries"];
    SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> "TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total],

    SparseArray @ Thread[data[[All,;;2]] -> data[[All,3]]],

    SetSystemOptions[old]
]
```

Compare this with @edmund's solution:

```
edmund[data_] := SparseArray @ Normal @ GroupBy[data, Most->Last, Total]
```

For example:

```
data[n_] := Join[RandomInteger[{1,10}, {n,2}], RandomReal[1., {n,1}], 2]

d6 = data[10^6];
r1 = carl[d6]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = edmund[d6]; //AbsoluteTiming
MinMax[r1-r2]
```

> {0.852608, Null}
>
> {1.26883, Null}
>
> {-1.00044*10^-11, 8.18545*10^-12}

The difference is due to the order in which the repeated entries are totaled in the two methods.

Comment: Great! I am curious, how do you know this?

Comment: @matheorem ``Experimental`SystemOptionsEditor[]`` is a nice way to view all of the available system options.

Comment: Wow, this is really amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: @matheorem you should read [(807)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/807/121) :-)

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html).

```
Clear[toSparse]
toSparse[data_] := SparseArray@Normal@GroupBy[data, Most -> Last, Total]
```

Then

```
toSparse[data[1000]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0019702, Null}
> ```

```
toSparse[data[10000]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0155542, Null}
> ```

```
toSparse[data[100000]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.181737, Null}
> ```

```
toSparse[data[1000000]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {2.0271, Null}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, @Edmund. Thank you so much for the solution. I am shocked that `GroupBy` can be so much faster than `Merge`, it seems that they perform very similar operation. What cause such a big difference?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any sparsity at all in this problem, given that we are adding values to `n` random elements of a 10x10 matrix, and `n` is up to $10^6$. So, given that we keep `data` as-is, the algorithm to fill the matrix is so straight-forward that it's a good candidate for compiling. I propose

```
makeMatrix = Compile[{{inds, _Integer, 2}, {vals, _Real, 1}},
  Block[{mat = Table[0., {10}, {10}]},
   Do[
    mat[[inds[[i, 1]], inds[[i, 2]]]] += vals[[i]]
    , {i, Length[vals]}
    ];
   mat
   ]
  , CompilationTarget -> "C"
  , RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ]
```

and a wrapper

```
marius[data_] := makeMatrix[data[[All, 1 ;; 2]], data[[All, 3]]]
```

Then, on my machine,

```
d6 = data[10^6];
r1 = carl[d6]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = edmund[d6]; //AbsoluteTiming
r3 = marius[d6]; //AbsoluteTiming
Max[Abs[r3 - r1]]
```

gives

> `{0.967007, Null}`
>
> `{1.571291, Null}`
>
> `{0.305536, Null}`
>
> `3.63798*10^-11`

Comment: Thank you for the fast compile solution