# Performance issue of Merge function

Tags: performance-tuning, associations, function-comparison

I am using mma 11.0.1

This post is related to my previous [faster way to merge data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148037/4742).

enlightened by Edmund's answer, I found a subtle performance issue of `Merge`

First, let's define

```
Clear[data];
data[n_] := Module[{tmp},
  tmp = Join[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {n, 2}], RandomReal[1., {n, 1}], 
    2];
  Thread[tmp[[;; , 1 ;; 2]] -> tmp[[;; , -1]]]]
```

then

```
test = Thread[data[1000][[;; , 1 ;; 2]] -> data[1000][[;; , -1]]];
GroupBy[test, First -> Last, Total] === Merge[test, Total]
(*True*)
```

now some timing

```
timing = Transpose@
  Table[test = 
    Thread[data[2^i][[;; , 1 ;; 2]] -> data[2^i][[;; , -1]]];
   {AbsoluteTiming[GroupBy[test, First -> Last, Total];][[1]], 
    AbsoluteTiming[Merge[test, Total];][[1]]}, {i, 1, 19}];

ListLogPlot[timing, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> {"GroupBy", "Merge"}]
```

This gives

[image]

We can see that the performance of `Merge` is severely getting worse only when Length of list exceeds a limit. What happened?

Answer (score 4):

Your benchmark code got a little twisted up so let's start with a cleaner test.

```
data[n_] := Thread[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {n, 2}] -> RandomReal[n]]

f1 = GroupBy[#, First -> Last, Total] &;
f2 = Merge[Total];

f1[#] === f2[#] & @ data[100]

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2}, data, TimeConstraint -> 20]
```

[image]

Okay, so I confirm your result in v10.1 under Windows as well.

Let's modify `data` to include a parameter controlling the number of unique elements, and try the test again with 1000^2 potential indexes.

```
ClearAll[data]
data[max_][n_] := Thread[RandomInteger[{1, max}, {n, 2}] -> RandomReal[n]]

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2}, data[1000], TimeConstraint -> 20]
```

[image]

Here `Merge` maintains an advantage across the test.

Let's go the other way and cause extreme duplication with only a few final "bins" for the data:

```
BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2}, data[2], TimeConstraint -> 20]
```

[image]

I conclude from this that `Merge` was designed for maximum performance on sets with many unique keys, at the possible expense of performance with a limited number of keys and extreme duplication.

See [Taliesin Beynon's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54865/121) to a performance question of my own for another apparent example of algorithmic trade-offs.  (Specifically the last paragraph.)

Comment: Hi, @Mr.Wizard. Thank you so much for through benchmark. But I doubt your viewpoint `Merge was designed for maximum performance on sets with many unique keys...` . I'd rather think they screw things up in designing `Merge` : )  Because no matter the condition of keys, `GroupBy` is performing well,  what is more, `SparseArray` is even faster.  If they design it the way like that, and doesn't mention anything in the documentation. Oh my god, that is really an intentional trap, because for my example in the post, I don't think `GroupBy` is more natural function to pick up with than `Merge`: )