# Generating a (sparse?) array from data

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays

I have a list:

```
{{pos_1,val_1},{pos_2,val_2},...}
```

and would like to generate an array of dimension `d`, with values `val_i` at positions`pos_i`, the rest being filled with `0`. I would assume that I shall use `SparseArray` but this function has a different form of argument:

```
{pos_1->val_1,pos_2->val_2,...}
```

Is there any simple way to transform one type of the argument into the other, or completely different approach shall be undertaken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another possibility is

```
SparseArray[Rule @@ Transpose[posval]]
```

I think the input syntax that gets processed the quickest among the documented ones would be

```
SparseArray[pos -> vals , dims]
```

where `pos` is a list of positions and `vals` is a list of values. This way, `pos` and `vals` can be `PackedArray`s which can be processed much faster. A list of the form you described cannot be packed in general. So *better not generate it this way*. Mapping `Rule` on the position-value pairs also unpacks arrays. Generate `pos` and `vals` independently. In general, this will be  much faster.

For additive matrix assembly, see also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37566/additive-sparsearray-assembly?rq=1).

Comment: Your suggestion works. Thank you! I just have noted another problem. In my array some positions are 0's. For simplicity I would just increment all positions by 1. At which stage it would be most efficient? Is it possible at the stage of generating the `SparseArray`?

Comment: You can use `{pos,vals} = Transpose[posval]; SparseArray[pos+1 -> vals , dims]`. This adds `1` onto all positions indices.

Comment: Thank you. It works.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

```
posval = Join[List /@ RandomSample[Tuples[Range[5], {2}], 10], 
   List/@RandomInteger[9, 10], 2]
```

> {{{2, 4}, 3}, {{2, 1}, 8}, {{3, 5}, 4}, {{2, 3}, 3}, {{5, 5}, 
>         4}, {{3, 2}, 8}, {{4, 5}, 8}, {{3, 1}, 6}, {{2, 5}, 2}, {{5, 1}, 8}}

```
dims = Max /@ Transpose[posval[[All, 1]]];
sa = SparseArray[Rule @@@ posval, dims];
```

> SparseArray[<10>, {5, 5}]

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ sa
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  8 & 0 & 3 & 3 & 2 \\
>  6 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 \\
>  8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

Answer (score 4):

For a list of the form: `list={{pos_1,val_1},{pos_2,val_2}}`

How about `SparseArray[Map[#[[1]] -> #[[2]] &, list]]` ?

Comment: I have tried and got the message `List expected at position 1 in SparseArray`. Can you give a working example?

Comment: sorry made a typo in the equation. I will add a full working example when I get access to MMA again