# How to speed up this SparseArray construction

Tags: performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

This code is (obviously) getting slower with the growing number of trials, currently running over 5 hours. This stylised example takes 2.5 minutes. It is not entirel illustrative as the real situation is much sparser and less spread out but I would not know how to condense this into the below example.

How can I speed it up? The **first section** defines the input, a set of two dimensional slabs in a 4 dimensional space (5 `racks` and 20 `shelves` are allocated via a random discrete number, where *slabs* are defined by `horStart`, `horEnd`, `verStart` and `verEnd` - also randomly - which define the coordinates of the boundaries via 2 dimensional array. The idea is to *stack the individual cells of these arrays and measure how high the stack becomes*.

```
rack = RandomInteger[5, trials];
shelf = RandomInteger[20, trials];
horStart = RandomInteger[100, trials];
verStart = RandomInteger[200, trials];
horEnd = 
 RandomChoice[{.8, .15, .04, .01} -> {0, 10, 100, 200}, trials] + 
  horStart;
verEnd = 
 RandomChoice[{.8, .15, .04, .01} -> {0, 10, 100, 200}, trials] + 
  verStart;
```

The whole set is subsequently assigned to `input`, which is a `List` of  `Integer` with length `6`, identifying the `rack` and `shelf` space, and how much what individual cells are taken up by the *slabs*.

```
input = {rack, shelf, horStart, verStart, horEnd, verEnd}\[Transpose];
```

The `sparseArray` needs to be initialised with a value for the dimensions.

```
reach = Max /@ {rack, shelf, horEnd, verEnd};
sa2 = SparseArray[{}, reach, 0];
```

The **second section** allocates this to a `SparseArray` where the number of overlaps are counted to identify how high the stacks will become.

The area of interest is:

```
sa2=SparseArray[{{ra_, sh_, hor_, ver_} /; 
     Apply[Or, 
      Or[And[ra == #1, sh == #2, Between[hor, {#3, #5}], 
          Between[ver, {#4, #6}]] & @@@ input]] :> (sa2[[ra, sh, 
       hor, ver]] + 1)}, reach]]
```

which is at the bottom of the below **integrated code**.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
sa = Module[{rack, shelf, horStart, verStart, horEnd, verEnd, 
     trials = 1000, input, reach, sa2},

(*first section: define rack, shelf and slab sizes to stack*)

rack = RandomInteger[5, trials];
shelf = RandomInteger[20, trials];
horStart = RandomInteger[100, trials];
verStart = RandomInteger[200, trials];
horEnd = 
 RandomChoice[{.8, .15, .04, .01} -> {0, 10, 100, 200}, trials] + 
  horStart;
verEnd = 
 RandomChoice[{.8, .15, .04, .01} -> {0, 10, 100, 200}, trials] + 
  verStart;
reach = Max /@ {rack, shelf, horEnd, verEnd};
input = {rack, shelf, horStart, verStart, horEnd, verEnd}\[Transpose];

(* second section, allocate to SparseArray, measure size of stacks *)

sa2 = SparseArray[{}, reach, 0];
sa2 = SparseArray[{{ra_, sh_, hor_, ver_} /; 
     Apply[Or, 
      Or[And[ra == #1, sh == #2, Between[hor, {#3, #5}], 
          Between[ver, {#4, #6}]] & @@@ input]] :> (sa2[[ra, sh, 
       hor, ver]] + 1)}, reach]];]


Out (* 140 *)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is super inefficient as it uses pattern matching and as to perform many more checks than there are nonzero entries in the final matrix. It is usually better to compute the sparse array pattern, i.e., the list of all nonzero positions. This is done by the following compiled function:

```
cf = Compile[{{r, _Integer}, {s, _Integer}, {hS, _Integer}, {vS, _Integer}, {hE, _Integer}, {vE, _Integer}},
   Flatten[Table[{r, s, i, j}, {i, hS, hE}, {j, vS, vE}], 1],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Now the matrix is assembled with

```
A = SparseArray[
   Join @@ cf[rack, shelf, horStart, verStart, horEnd, verEnd] -> 1, 
   reach];
```

For `trials = 1000`, this takes less than a 10000th part of the time.

Edit: *Additive* assembly can be done with the following helper function:

```
MySparseArray[R_Rule, dims_?VectorQ, fun_: Total, background_: 0] :=
 With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]},
  Internal`WithLocalSettings[
   SetSystemOptions[
    "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> fun}],
   SparseArray[R, dims, background],
   SetSystemOptions[spopt]]
  ]
```

and then

```
A = MySparseArray[
   Join @@ cf[rack, shelf, horStart, verStart, horEnd, verEnd] -> 1, 
   reach, Total, 0];
```

Comment: Thank you, will this work for the `:> (sa2[[ra, sh, 
       hor, ver]] + 1)` as in the end of example code?

Comment: `A` will satisfy `A==sa2`. So yes.

Comment: You are right, something else is wrong. That part of the code should cumulate each time a slab is covering that cell. It seems not to do this anymore; something behaves different in my toy example than in the actual one I have been working with. I can't find out what, sorry ... am looking into it.

Comment: Ah, I see. So you want an _additive_ assembly. This can be done...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher You're the SparseArray master.

Comment: @ChrisK Thank you! That's because I find SparseArrays very useful. =D

Comment: Wow Henrik, this is an (embarrasing) massive improvement. Thanks ...

Comment: Henrik, I was looking for documentation and could not rreally find anything. I referred to your solution in this post, however suggest you add your own and I will remove my entry. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/what-are-sparsearray-properties-how-and-when-should-they-be-used/83722#83722

Comment: Hmm. I think this is where I learnt this technique: [(37607)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37607). I am not too happy with posting [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212837) as an answer to a question about `"Properties"`; the latter are string arguments for a `SparseArray` that reveal some of the internal data of this data structure. In contrast, `"TreatRepeatedEntries"` is a global option.

Comment: Understood ... the reference you provide is more to the point; however I (or others) would highly unlikely have found this looking for a global option. In which case being correct would defeat the purpose of a usefull reference a bit? Let me know, happy either way.

Comment: I'd say: Leave things as they are know and let the other users decide whether [(212837)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2128370) is useful. =)