# Product of non-zero elements in sparse array

Tags: sparse-arrays

How can I multiply the non-zero elements of a `SparseArray`?

Example:

```
a = SparseArray[{1 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 7 -> 3}]
Times @@ a (* this returns 0, but I need 6! *)
```

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31963/121

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note the following:

1. The sparse array a is:

   ```
    {1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3}
   ```

   hence applying `Times` to this yields zero
2. You can see the underlying array using `Normal`

   ```
     a // Normal
   ```
3. You could multiply the non-zero elements of a sparse array object:

   ```
    Times @@ a["NonzeroValues"]
   ```

Comment: This is good to know! Could you perhaps point me to the documentation where `"NonzeroValues"` is mentioned?

Comment: @Danvil As far as I know it isn't documented.  You can see the other `SparseArray` Properties with:  `SparseArray[{1}]["Properties"]`. I gathered links to some of my uses of these in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23623/121).