# Isn't it possible to Pack a SparseArray?

Tags: packed-arrays

I have the following matrix `Va`:

```
Va = Table[
Which[i == j + 1, 2, True, 0], {l, 1, 2}, {m, 1, 2}, {s, 1,
 2}, {q, 1, 2}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1,2}];
```

There is no problem to pack it:

```
Va = Developer`ToPackedArray[Va];

Print@Developer`PackedArrayQ@Va;

True
```

But then there is the matrix `Vb`, which is the same as `Va`, but in the `SparseArray` form:

```
Vb = SparseArray[{l_, m_, s_, q_, i_, j_} :> 
Which[i == j + 1, 2, True, 0], {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}];
```

And this one I can not Pack:

```
Vb = Developer`ToPackedArray[Vb];

Print@Developer`PackedArrayQ@Vb;

False
```

Does anybody know the way to pack this `SparseArray` `Vb`?

Comment: Have a look at `Vb["Properties"]` It's stuff like the `"NonzeroValues"` you want to be packed. (Can't really provide more detail, but I've found SparseArrays to be faster when the properties are packed arrays)

Comment: To be a packed array, one first has to have an array (not a `SparseArray`).  Try ``Developer`PackedArrayQ @ Normal@Vb``.

Comment: @ Michael E2 indeed, if you convert the SparseArray into an array, you can Pack it, but the reason why I use SparseArray is because I have memory issues, therefore I assume I will have memory problems when I convert my SparseArray into an array.

Comment: But it seems to be the only option since, apparently there is no way to Pack an SparseArray.

Comment: I believe @ssch is right.  The relevant parts of the `SparseArray` are packed, if possible.  There is some computational overhead with a `SparseArray`, but generally they are efficient.  I'm not sure, but I think you have to be careful that some operations do not convert a sparse array to a full array.

Comment: I agree with Michael. I think for packed we should read: "storing machine integers as opposed to larger objects  (structs from C)". I know that a packed array is nothing but a thin data structure (struct) around an array of machine integers (in this case). That can be found out by using LibraryLink. I am not certain that a "normal mathematica integer" is a struct, maybe Michael's linksnooper skills can help there. Anyway, I would be very surprised if `SparseArray` called on a list of integers would produce a data structure in which structs were stored rather than machine integers.

Comment: So yeah its already packed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment, but I think it is useful information in the context of this question. No, `SparseArray`s cannot *be* packed, because a packed array and a sparse array are completely different and unrelated data structures. But, a sparse array can be *constructed from* packed arrays. Let's look at an example:

```
Vb = SparseArray[
 {l_, m_, s_, q_, i_, j_} :> Which[i == j + 1, 2, True, 0],
 {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}
];
```

This is the array from the question. Now we consider its internal structure:

```
Vb /. Verbatim[SparseArray][args__] :> {args}
     /. _List?Developer`PackedArrayQ -> "packed"
```

(Here we are just stripping off the `SparseArray` head to produce a list of arguments, and then substituting `"packed"` in place of any packed arrays that appeared there.)

Some of its parts are packed, but not all:

```
(* -> {Automatic, "packed", 0,
       {1, {"packed", "packed"}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}}
      } *)
```

We can try to pack all the parts by converting it into an ordinary array, packing it, and then converting back into a sparse array. (I can't see any way to pack it from the start if we choose to define it using a conditional statement.)

```
Vb2 = SparseArray@Developer`ToPackedArray@Normal[Vb];
Vb2 /. Verbatim[SparseArray][args__] :> {args}
      /. _List?Developer`PackedArrayQ -> "packed"
(* -> {Automatic, "packed", 0, {1, {"packed", "packed"}, "packed"}} *)
```

Here we see that the list of non-zero values was packed by this process, although nothing else changed. It suggests that we can avoid having to unpack it fully, and just pack the relevant list by ourselves:

```
Vb3 = Vb /. Verbatim[SparseArray][args__] :> 
             SparseArray @@ MapAt[Developer`ToPackedArray, {args}, {4, 3}];
Vb3 /. Verbatim[SparseArray][args__] :> {args}
      /. _List?Developer`PackedArrayQ -> "packed"
(* -> {Automatic, "packed", 0, {1, {"packed", "packed"}, "packed"}} *)
```

Regarding the meaning of the parts of the `SparseArray` structure, I would suggest reviewing Oliver Ruebenkoenig's answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18081/how-to-interpret-the-fullform-of-a-sparsearray) question, and Leonid's API for manipulating them as presented [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/287) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609071).