# Building sparse array from packed arrays

Tags: performance-tuning, memory, sparse-arrays, packed-arrays

Suppose I have two *large* packed arrays `a` and `b`, that respectively contain the position of the elements of a *square* matrix (i.e. `a` has the explicit form {{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},...}) and the value for each matrix element (i.e. `b` has the explicit form {0.2938,0.091,-0.4984,...}).

**Now, is there a way to build a sparse array from `a` and `b` without having unpacking in the internal process of creating the sparse array ?**

**Refining the question + example below:** The usual `SparseArray[a->b]` command seems have some unpacking in the process although a and b are unaffected. Really, what I'm concerned about is : suppose you have `memA=ByteCount[a]` and `memB=ByteCount[b]`.

In the process of constructing `c=SparseArray[a->b]` *I do not want my kernel to suck up all my memory by unpacking a or b (or doing some other unpacking in the internal code)*, i.e. the kernel memory required during the process should not exceed something like memA+memB, which seems like a very natural requirement to me... In eldo's answer below, it seems there is no unpacking since the arrays considered are too small. Considering larger arrays will lead to the above mentioned problem.

**Is there a simple solution (or not so simple) to this issue ?**

*Specific example:

```
On["Packing"] 

a=Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, 1, 10000000}]; (* Position of the elements *)
b=Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 10000000}]; (* Value of the elements *)
c=SparseArray[{a -> b}]; (* Generating the sparse array *)
ByteCount[a]
ByteCount[b]
ByteCount[c]
```

> 80000168
>
> 80000168
>
> 160000952

Plus you get the following messages :

> FromPackedArray::punpack: Unpacking array with dimensions {10000000,2}
>   in call to Rule. >>
>   FromPackedArray::punpack: Unpacking array with dimensions {10000000}
>   in call to Rule. >>
>   FromPackedArray::punpack1: Unpacking array with dimensions {10000000}.>>

So it seems there is some unpacking in the internal process. In this specific examples the kernel memory during the process goes up by 1 GB, although the final results takes only 160 MB...

```
$Version
```

> 8.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (October 5, 2011)

Comment: Answered here: [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38867/isnt-it-possible-to-pack-a-sparsearray)

Comment: I looked at that answer, but I didn't understand how this could be applied to my problem. I guess what I'm asking here is : is there a simple command such as SparseArray[A->B] to generate the sparse array from A and B ?

Comment: It looks like there is some internal unpacking going on, for large enough lists. It is possible to construct the pieces of the SparseArray without unpacking, but it looks like they are still unpacked internally.

Comment: Your comment at `On["Packing"]` is incorrect. It just switches on unpacking warnings. It does not AFAIK influence packing itself.

Comment: Right. I made the update.

Comment: @VanillaSpinIce - I get the following results: `a = 160000152`, `b = 80000144` and `c = 400000728`. No Warnings. Please change your `C` to `c`. `C` is a protected symbol.

Comment: @eldo : Oups again, I just made another update

Comment: @eldo: This is strange. I clearly get a warning message because of unpacking (but it seems you don't). Can you monitor your kernel memory allocation ? Does it require lots of memory while you run the above code ?

Comment: @VanillaSpinIce Running your above code takes me about 8.5 seconds. When I used various memory functions they didn't show any anomalies. But I just realized that nasty problems occur when I run the code four or five times. At a certain point the whole system froze and I had to restart the computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 10.1 under Windows I find that a subtle syntax difference is *critical* to this issue.

**The form `SparseArray[{a -> b}]` causes unpacking while `SparseArray[a -> b]` does not.  Further this affects the *output* of `SparseArray` itself, not only its memory consumption during creation.**

```
On["Packing"]

a = {#, # + 1}\[Transpose] & @ Range @ 1*^6;
b = RandomReal[1, 1*^6];
c = SparseArray[a -> b];

Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {a,b}

MaxMemoryUsed[]
ByteCount[c]
```

> ```
> {True, True}
>
> 85279216
>
> 24000792
> ```

In a fresh session the exact same code as above adding only the brackets around `a -> b`

```
On["Packing"]

a = {#, # + 1}\[Transpose] & @ Range @ 1*^6;
b = RandomReal[1, 1*^6];
c = SparseArray[{a -> b}];    (* <-------- CRITICAL SYNTAX DIFFERENCE *)

Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {a,b}

MaxMemoryUsed[]
ByteCount[c]
```

> Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack: Unpacking array with dimensions {1000000,2} in call to Rule. >>
>
> Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack: Unpacking array with dimensions {1000000} in call to Rule. >>
>
> ```
> {True, True}
>
> 286566696
>
> 40000728
> ```

The two objects are functionally equivalent despite the size difference:

```
c1 = SparseArray[a -> b];
c2 = SparseArray[{a -> b}];

ByteCount /@ {c1, c2}

c1 === c2
```

> ```
> {24000792, 40000728}
>
> True
> ```

I surmise that specific optimizations exist in `SparseArray` for exactly your application, however the syntax is brittle and the optimization is not triggered for `{a -> b}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Needs["Developer`"];

a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {99, 2}} // ToPackedArray;

b = {1.1, 1.2, 1.3} // ToPackedArray;

c = SparseArray[a -> b];

PackedArrayQ /@ {a, b, c}
```

> {True, True, False}

Hence, `a` and `b` were NOT unpacked.

**UPDATE**

```
Needs["Developer`"];

a = Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, 1, 10000000}];
b = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 10000000}];
c = SparseArray[{a -> b}];

ByteCount /@ {a, b, c}
```

> {160000152, 80000144, 400000728}

```
PackedArrayQ /@ {a, b, c}
```

> {True, True, False}

No Warnings.

```
$Version
```

> "9.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 25, 2013)"

Comment: There is unpacking if you try this on larger arrays, of e.g. 100 elements. But to see it, you have to enable `On["Packing"]` before running the code.

Comment: Exactly ! Is there a way to avoid this ? In the example given by eldo, the arrays are indeed too small to have the unpacking.

Comment: @VanillaSpinIce Not that I know of (which doesn't mean there isn't). It seems that the unpacking is done in the internal code, which constructs the sparse array. I wrote some code which constructs the sparse array from pieces at lower level, but the unpacking was still there - thus I did not post it.

Comment: @ Leonid Shifrin Ah, I see. It seems that being able to do such a thing would be such a big plus for using Mathematica for large sparse matrix diagonalization... meaning that you can increase the size of the matrix you are looking at by a factor of 4 or 8. I think this would be of great interest for many physicists that are interest in exact diagonalization of quantum systems.

Comment: "Unpacking" here refers to temporary unpacking.  In other words, the internal representation of `a`, `b` is not changed permanently. `PackedArrayQ[a]` will always give `True`.  However, during the process of creating the `SparseArray`, an unpacked version of `a`,`b` is created in memory temporarily.  These can take up a *lot* of memory, and the unpacking process can be very slow (in general, I don't know how big an issue it is in the specific case of creating a `SparseArray`). Before evaluating this test code, make sure you do `On["Packing"]` which will turn on warnings about unpacking events.

Comment: @Szabolcs Is there any way around that ?

Comment: @VanillaSpinIce I'm sure there's no *easy* way around that.  You can study the internal representation of SparseArray and create it yourself.  It might still unpack though, and it's not a trivial thing to do ...  From Leonid's comment it sounded like he tried just that.  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18081/12  I wouldn't spend any more time on this, but one can never be *sure* that there is not solution, of course ...

Comment: @ Szabolcs : I see. Thanks for the reference. Do you have an idea why SparseArray[a->b] is doing this ? I mean it seems like a sort of bug/programming mistake to me that this unpacking is being done in the process.

Comment: @ eldo : I just updated to version 9.0 ! And the problem is even worse : now the bytecount for a,b,c respectively reads 160 000 000,80 000 000,400 000 000 !