# Unexpected timing result of Total and Part performance of packed array

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, packed-arrays

Define

```
a = RandomReal[1., {2, 100, 100, 100}];
```

then

```
Total[a, Infinity]; // RepeatedTiming
{0.00183727, Null}
```

and

```
Total[a[[1]], Infinity]; // RepeatedTiming
{0.00879665, Null}
```

Why? half work takes much more time?

---

**update**

This post has envolved into a post about the Part performance of packed array. As we all know, packed arrays stand for better performance and space efficiency over unpacked array, and we [try hard not to get into the unpacking process](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5258/4742).

However, it is clear now, `Part` operation of packed array may suffer severe copying issue(as Michael E2 analyzed). So in my case, to store packed sub data inside a unpacked list turns out to be a better choice.

```
aa = {RandomReal[1., {100, 100, 100}], RandomReal[1., {100, 100, 100}]};
Total[aa[[1]], Infinity]; // RepeatedTiming
{0.000676956, Null}
```

However, problems remains:

1. Is there direct way to speed up Parting of packed array?
2. Is it inevitable for Mathematica to have this `Part` behavior on packed array due to its design? (I guess not, because assignment like `a[[1,;;,;;,;;]]=1.` do not suffer)

Comment: Did you check packing?

Comment: @J.M. `On["Packing"]` shows nothing

Comment: Extract the part separately and you'll see that the timing difference has nothing to do with `Total`: `part = a[[1]]; RepeatedTiming[Total[part, Infinity];]`

Comment: Obvious workaround that does too much work but is fast: `Total[a, {2, Infinity}][[1]]`

Comment: @MarcoB That still blows my mind even if I used mathematica for years. I tried python numpy, `np.sum(a[1])` got exactly half time of `np.sum(a)`. Is there a way to get half timing in Mathematica like numpy?

Comment: I get significantly different timings (Intel i7 Mac): https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRQTv.png

Comment: @MichaelE2 That is even more wierd. Which version do you use? I use mma 12. on windows. What on earth happend to `Part`? Does `Part` make a copy? Why is it not the case on your system?

Comment: V12.2. It's what I would expect. It's similar to what I get running MarcoB's code, so I'm not sure what's weird. You get something different?

Comment: mathorem, it may play a part also how each platform measures the time used for such operations.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah, I got opposite timing https://imgur.com/joJ5fjd

Comment: @matheorem Your code is not the same as mine.  My `RepeatedTiming` is inside `With[]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oops...My bad

Comment: @MichaelE2 Hi, MichaelE2. I searched the site and can not get a clear clue. It seems that `Part` performance was rarely mentioned.  Is slow `Part` is due to that `Part` create a copy? Is there a way to get rid of copy? I found assignment like `a[[;; , ;; , ;; , ;;]] = 1.` is faster than `a[[1]]`

Comment: I added an answer explaining things as I understand them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Update: I rewrote most of the text in response to the OP's comments.  I suspect what I wrote originally lacked clarity.  I hope I have improved it.*]

The extra time observed in `Total[aa // First, Infinity]` comes from copying the data in `aa[[1]]`.  It resembles unpacking in that it adds time to the computation that seems unnecessary.  Indeed, in unpacked arrays, the copying of `aa[[1]]` does not occur.  The differences in unpacked and packed arrays are explained below.  Since `aa // First` is evaluated before `Total` is called, the problem is with `Part` and not `Total`.  The time it takes to copy the first `Part` of the array accounts for the difference in timing.

```
aa = RandomReal[1., {2, 100, 100, 100}];

aa // First; // RepeatedTiming
With[{a1 = aa // First}, Total[a1, Infinity]; // RepeatedTiming]

% + %%
Total[aa // First, Infinity]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> (*
>   {0.00184571, Null}   <-- extracting aa[[1]]
>   {0.000277292, Null}  <-- Total[]
>   
>   {0.002123, 2 Null}   <-- sum of preceding two times
>   {0.00214796, Null}   <-- Total[aa // First...]
> *)
> ```

Now I will describe how the difference of a packed array from a regular `List` array factors into the timing here.

A regular `List` array `lis`, constructed by entering `lis = {{11, 12, 13}, {21, 22, 23}}`, is represented internally by a pointer to a (linked) list of pointers to the expressions  `{11, 12, 13}` and `{21, 22, 23}`.  The part `l1 = lis[[1]]` is a pointer to an expression.  There is no need to copy the expression unless it is changed in either `lis` or `l1`, and *Mathematica* will not copy it until such a change occurs.  This is one of the efficiencies implemented in the everything-is-an-expression approach that WRI initially adopted for *Mathematica*.

A packed array `pa` is represented internally by an `MTensor`, which is a pointer to a structure `st_MNumericArray`, whose definitions can be found in the `$InstallationDirectory` in `"SystemFiles/IncludeFiles/WolframLibrary.h"`  and `".../WolframCompileLibrary.h"` respectively.  This structure includes information about the type, rank, and dimensions of the array, a pointer to the numeric data, plus some other bookkeeping information.  The numeric data is stored as a flat list of numbers (the same way as in C).  The parts of the array are not stored as separate expressions, as in the regular `List` array.  In order to maintain the everything-is-an-expression approach, when a part `p1 = pa[[1]]` is evaluated, a new expression must be constructed and part of the numeric data is copied into the new packed array. (One imagines one could implement a "subarray" structure that would need only a pointer to the numeric data in `pa` plus information defining the subarray and whatever additional bookkeeping might be needed.  Whether this would be worth it is a design choice, and I cannot evaluate the trade-offs.)

When a packed array is converted to a `List` array, the process is called "unpacking."  It involves constructing expressions and copying the data.  It can be expensive.  A packed array can be unpacked down to any level.  The further down the unpacking goes, the more expensive it is.  Taking a part of a packed array also involves constructing an expression and copying data, but it is not called "unpacking."  It can still be expensive in way that makes long-time users suspect unpacking.

To test the foregoing, we check the timing in an unpacked array.  And we see that totaling the first part is faster than totaling the whole array:

```
up = Developer`FromPackedArray[aa, 1]; (* unpacks to level 1 only *)
Total[up // First, Infinity]; // RepeatedTiming
Total[aa, Infinity]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> (*
>   {0.000276366, Null}  *)
>   {0.000793719, Null}  *)
> *)
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much, Michael E2. Acutally I was just about to update my post to talk about that unpacked list of packed array is a better choice in this case :)  I still got questions. First, what are those `punpack1` and `punpack11` messages? I never saw these message.

Comment: You said "Mathematica copies a structure only when a program tries to change (part of) its value ". But in assignment case `a[[1, ;; , ;; , ;;]] = 1.`, the `a` is gonna changing, but I guess no copy happened, it is an inplace update, because it is indeed much faster.  So I am wondering if `Part` of packed array really has to be copied due to mathematica's maybe immutability design principle?

Comment: After all, for built-in functions like `Total` and basic arithmetics, there should be special branches to prevent this kind of copy. If not, that is a shame for packed array to be the common choice of faster and more efficient over unpacked array.

Comment: The messages are what you get with `On["Packing"]`. -- Try `b = a; a[[1, ;; , ;; , ;;]] = 1.`. Then the array `a` pointed to will be copied to preserve the value of `b`.  Time this with a 1GB+ array for `a` and it will be obvious. Mathematica must keep a table of references to an expression. -- I disagree with your last comment. `Total` does not hold its arguments.  `a[[1]]` is copied before `Total` is called; see my example `aa // First` above.  The fault, if you want to call it that, is with `Part`, which I alluded to in my second-to-last paragraph ("I don't know enough...").

Comment: Hi, Michael E2. But I didn't see any message generated with `On["Packing"]` when evaluating `Total[aa // First, Infinity];`

Comment: Sorry, Michael E2. But I got confused. If you didn't see the message, why do you mention punpack1 message? Are you just guessing it is happened？ By the way, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51728/building-sparse-array-from-packed-arrays?rq=1 this post says punpack shows up when `On["Packing"]`, but I can not see punpack in 12.2 by running their code.

Comment: @matheorem I was trying to distinguish behavior that leads to unpacking messages from what happens here, which unpack/copies part of level 1 of `a` but not all of `a` and does not yield a message.

Answer (score 7):

Included in your timing is the `Part` operation. Try:

```
b = a[[1]];
Total[b, Infinity]; // RepeatedTiming
```