# How to prevent a SparseArray entry from being specified when it coincides with the default value?

Tags: sparse-arrays

*Mathematica* doesn't notice when an entry coincides with the default value:

```
(IdentityMatrix[2, SparseArray] - IdentityMatrix[2, SparseArray])["NonzeroPositions"]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}

How to make it notice this?

Comment: Workaround: `SparseArray[(IdentityMatrix[2, SparseArray] - IdentityMatrix[2, SparseArray])]["NonzeroPositions"]`. Related: [Efficient way to combine SparseArray objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276/efficient-way-to-combine-sparsearray-objects) See also: [What are SparseArray Properties? How and when should they be used?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/what-are-sparsearray-properties-how-and-when-should-they-be-used)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As corey979 pointed out, wrap it with `SparseArray`. Moreover, it is also discussed in the section "Possible Issues" in the documentation of `SparseArray`.

In any cases, automatic "nullifying" of zero entries would harm performance as the internal structure of the sparse array (i.e., `A["RowPointers"]`, `A["ColumnIndices"]`, and `A["NonzeroPositions"]`) would have to be recomputed. (Note that internally, `SparseArray`s are stored in the [CRS format](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_Row_Storage). See also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44900/38178) for the Mathematica-specfic details.) As few zero-valued nonzero entries usually do not harm, it is a good thing to have it under user control.

There are even use cases in which an automatic "nullifying" of zero-valued nonzero entries would be harmful (although I cannot recall a case where that was an issue when using only in-built functions). For example, I frequently use the MKL Pardiso solver through library link. That enables me to factor a matrix `A`, then change only the values of `A`, and recycle most of the data that Pardiso computed internally -- provided that `A["NonzeroPositions"]` does not change. That's very useful, e.g.,  for Newton's method. It would be a tedious task if Mathematica would "nullify" entries "at random".